# Are there any legitimate use-cases for "goto" in a language that supports loops and functions?

Tags: language-agnostic, goto

I've long been under the impression that `goto` should never be used if possible.

However, while perusing libavcodec (which is written in C) the other day, I was surprised to notice multiple uses of it.

Is it ever advantageous to use `goto` in a language that supports loops and functions?  If so, why?   Please provide a concrete example that clearly justifies the use of a `goto`.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

There are a few reasons for using the "goto" statement that I'm aware of (some have spoken to this already):

**Cleanly exiting a function**

Often in a function, you may allocate resources and need to exit in multiple places.  Programmers can simplify their code by putting the resource cleanup code at the end of the function, and all "exit points" of the function would goto the cleanup label.  This way, you don't have to write cleanup code at every "exit point" of the function.

**Exiting nested loops**

If you're in a nested loop and need to break out of *all* loops, a goto can make this much cleaner and simpler than break statements and if-checks.

**Low-level performance improvements**

This is only valid in perf-critical code, but goto statements execute very quickly and can give you a boost when moving through a function.  This is a double-edged sword, however, because a compiler typically cannot optimize code that contains gotos.

Note that in all these examples, gotos are restricted to the scope of a single function.

Comment: The right way to exit nested loops is to refactor the inner loop into a separate method.

Comment: @Jason - Bah. That's a load of bull. Replacing `goto` with `return` is just silly. It's not "refactoring" anything, it's just "renaming" so that people who grew up in a `goto`-suppressed environment (i.e. all of us) feel better about using what morally amounts to a `goto`. I much prefer to see the loop _where I use it_ and see a little `goto`, which by itself is _just a tool_, than see someone having moved the loop somewhere unrelated just to avoid a `goto`.

Comment: There are sitations where gotos are important: for instance, an exception-less C++ environment. In the Silverlight source we have tens of thousands (or more) of goto statements for safe function exist through the use of macros - key media codecs and libraries often work through return values and never exceptions, and it's difficult to combine these error handling mechanisms in a single performant way.

Comment: It's worth noting that all `break`,`continue`,`return` are basically `goto`, just in nice packaging.

Comment: For the cleanly exiting a function point, an alternative is to use a `do{/*code goes here*/}while(0);` and use break (or continue :D) to leave it. No labels.

Comment: Example of use of labeled break in String.java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful/14960832#14960832

Comment: exit() doesn't work in an apache module.  I made wrapper function called exit()... that did a goto.

Comment: A note for cleanly exiting a function: Chris talks about multiple exit points, this would be solved by having only one exit point per function.

Comment: I don't see how `do{....}while(0)` is supposed to be a better idea than goto, except for the fact it works in Java.

Comment: @DaanTimmer The problem is that this often leads to quite unreadable code, either with deep nesting or a bunch of "helper" variables. Exiting early is incredible for readability - provided your language is optimized for this (e.g. exceptions, (at least partially) managed memory, ...). Of course, C#'s `finally` statement makes this a breeze - a much nicer "wrapper" to do any required clean-up. I've seen a few valid reasons to use `goto`; in all cases, I had to rewrite the same thing as a loop (even though it wasn't a loop!) just to avoid writing the dreaded `goto`. That hurt readability.

Comment: @Luaan, These witch-hunts are still going on apparently.  Absurd that students carry with them the nonsense they were taught as gospel.  It's amazing the contortions folks will go through to avoid the goto.  Take a look at Jason's comment at the top.  Amazing....I was so hoping this nonsense would have finally died in the 90's.

Comment: As to multiple return avoidance (oye), consider: at the point you wish to exit, why is it better to set state and cascade that state downward to a particular exit point rather than simply return?  You gain ***nothing*** by this.  The *only* argument for it holding any water at all was to have testing and/or clean up code at the exit point.  Also, *sometimes* profiling is more easily done this way.  But both of those reasons are very weak.  It's much easier to read code that actually returns from multiple places rather than sets a cascading state from multiple places!

Comment: @tgm1024 If only this was a problem just with programmers :) I don't know about the schools you've seen, but most I've seen (and heard about) are very heavy on the "learn the answers for the test" and very light on "actually understand the subject matter". The former leads to accepting things as gospel, the latter to being able to think about whether the "rule" makes sense here or not. If you don't understand the experience, you will not be very likely to improve upon it. Feynman's teaching experience in Brazil being a terrifying and sobering read - http://tinyurl.com/braziledu

Comment: Frank Rubin published a criticism of Dijkstra's letter in the March 1987 CACM where it appeared under the title 'GOTO Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful.[7] The May 1987 CACM printed further replies, both for and against, under the title '"GOTO Considered Harmful" Considered Harmful' Considered Harmful?.[8] Dijkstra's own response to this controversy was titled On a Somewhat Disappointing Correspondence.[9]

Comment: You forgot a really good reason: because Don Knuth uses goto in The Art of Computer Programming.

Comment: In addition to "cleanly exiting a function", there are more generic cases of multiple paths that lead to common code, such as the last example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844613/34845789#34845789). It's a performance oriented 4 way merge sort, using if statements rather than a minheap to determine the run with the smallest leading element, and there are two paths to each case. In addition, when nearing the end of the array, or when merging reaches the end of a run, there's a drop down to 3 way merge, then 2 way, then copy the rest of the remaining run.

Comment: One more case is python's Loop-Else - to handle a situation, when iteration didn't find anything. Without the `else` it generally requires a flag variable, but can be solved with goto bypassing the `else` block

Answer (score 951):

Everybody who is anti-`goto` cites, directly or indirectly, Edsger Dijkstra's [GoTo Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) article to substantiate their position.  Too bad Dijkstra's article has virtually *nothing* to do with the way `goto` statements are used these days and thus what the article says has little to no applicability to the modern programming scene.  The `goto`-less meme verges now on a religion, right down to its scriptures dictated from on high, its high priests and the shunning (or worse) of perceived heretics.

Let's put Dijkstra's paper into context to shed a little light on the subject.

When Dijkstra wrote his paper the popular languages of the time were unstructured procedural ones like BASIC, FORTRAN (the earlier dialects) and various assembly languages.  It was quite common for people using the higher-level languages to jump *all over their code base* in twisted, contorted threads of execution that gave rise to the term "spaghetti code".  You can see this by hopping on over to [the classic Trek game](http://web.archive.org/web/20150215080553/http://www.dunnington.u-net.com/public/startrek/STTR1) written by Mike Mayfield and trying to figure out how things work.  Take a few moments to look that over.

**THIS** is "the unbridled use of the go to statement" that Dijkstra was railing against in his paper in 1968.  **THIS** is the environment he lived in that led him to write that paper.  The ability to jump anywhere you like in your code at any point you liked was what he was criticising and demanding be stopped.  Comparing that to the anaemic powers of `goto` in C or other such more modern languages is simply risible.

I can already hear the raised chants of the cultists as they face the heretic.  "But," they will chant, "you can make code very difficult to read with `goto` in C."  Oh yeah?  You can make code very difficult to read without `goto` as well.  Like this one:

```
#define _ -F<00||--F-OO--;
int F=00,OO=00;main(){F_OO();printf("%1.3f\n",4.*-F/OO/OO);}F_OO()
{
            _-_-_-_
       _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
        _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
            _-_-_-_
}
```

Not a `goto` in sight, so it must be easy to read, right?  Or how about this one:

```
a[900];     b;c;d=1     ;e=1;f;     g;h;O;      main(k,
l)char*     *l;{g=      atoi(*      ++l);       for(k=
0;k*k<      g;b=k       ++>>1)      ;for(h=     0;h*h<=
g;++h);     --h;c=(     (h+=g>h     *(h+1))     -1)>>1;
while(d     <=g){       ++O;for     (f=0;f<     O&&d<=g
;++f)a[     b<<5|c]     =d++,b+=    e;for(      f=0;f<O
&&d<=g;     ++f)a[b     <<5|c]=     d++,c+=     e;e= -e
;}for(c     =0;c<h;     ++c){       for(b=0     ;b<k;++
b){if(b     <k/2)a[     b<<5|c]     ^=a[(k      -(b+1))
<<5|c]^=    a[b<<5      |c]^=a[     (k-(b+1     ))<<5|c]
;printf(    a[b<<5|c    ]?"%-4d"    :"    "     ,a[b<<5
|c]);}      putchar(    '\n');}}    /*Mike      Laman*/
```

No `goto` there either.  It must therefore be readable.

What's my point with these examples?  It's not language features that make unreadable, unmaintainable code.  It's not syntax that does it.  It's bad programmers that cause this.  And bad programmers, as you can see in that above item, can make **any** language feature unreadable and unusable.  Like the `for` loops up there.  (You can see them, right?)

Now to be fair, some language constructs are easier to abuse than others.  If you're a C programmer, however, I'd peer far more closely at about 50% of the uses of `#define` long before I'd go on a crusade against `goto`!

So, for those who've bothered to read this far, there are several key points to note.

1. Dijkstra's paper on `goto` statements was written for a programming environment where `goto` was a *lot*
   more potentially damaging than it is in most modern languages that aren't an assembler.
2. Automatically throwing away all uses of `goto` because of this is about as rational as saying "I tried
   to have fun once but didn't like it so now I'm against it".
3. There are legitimate uses of the modern (anaemic) `goto` statements in code that cannot be adequately
   replaced by other constructs.
4. There are, of course, illegitimate uses of the same statements.
5. There are, too, illegitimate uses of the modern control statements like the "`godo`" abomination where an always-false `do` loop is broken out of using `break` in place of a `goto`.  These are often worse than judicious use of `goto`.

Comment: "I'd peer far more closely at about 50% of the uses of #define  long before I'd go on a crusade against goto!" <-- In fact, you can do both!

Comment: … @sgm has already said it: that’s one huge pile of logical fallacies. I just want to comment on one thing: You said you have used `goto` 3 times in the past x years – tell me, how does this compare to *any* other “general-purpose” language feature (I explicitly exclude specialized, yet sometimes necessary language features such as `volatile` which some people just don’t need)? Isn’t it odd that a *general-purpose* language feature gets used so little in good code? For me, that’s a strong indication that `goto` doesn’t bring much to the table. I.e., that it is defective. Go figure.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Let me rephrase your comment to show you the defect in your thinking.  "I explicitly exclude exactly the kinds of language features that would undermine my so-called 'argument', so how do you justify this other language feature?"

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: That is not at all like what I said. Just because two sentences are syntactically similar does not make them semantically equivalent. `volatile` is a non-redundant (i.e. cannot be replicated otherwise) special language feature. `goto` is general-purpose, and completely on-orthogonal with other language features.

Comment: -1 for "Other things are bad, so `goto` can't be" arguments. I'm pretty sure the people arguing against `goto` would also be against the code you listed.

Comment: "There are legitimate uses of the modern (anaemic) goto statements in code that cannot be adequately replaced by other constructs." Can you put an example?

Comment: @pocjoc: Writing tail-recursive optimization in C, for example. This comes up in implementation of functional language interpreters/runtimes, but is representative of an interesting category of problems. Most compilers written in C make use of goto for this reason. Its a niche use that doesn't occur in most situations, of course, but in the situations it is called for it makes a *lot* of sense to use.

Comment: @zxq9, You can do tail recursion in C by just wrapping the function body in a loop so `int f(int a, int b) { if (a < 10) return a; return f(a + b, b); }` becomes `int f(int a, int b) { for (;;;) { if (a < 10) { return a; } a += b; continue; } }` where tail-calls are rewritten to reassign parameters and `continue` to the top of the loop.

Comment: Why does everybody talk about Dijkstra's "Go to considered harmful" paper without mentioning Knuth's reply to it, "Structured programming with go to statements"?

Comment: I read the article why you no longer contribute at SO and jumped here. Indeed I fully agree 'it is not the language (goto) that makes software readable and maintainable but the way you use it'. I have been critized in the mid-eighties when I wrote VERY readable and maintainable code using goto just BECAUSE I just goto. I used goto to simulate private functions combined with datahidding in FORTRAN. Several years later some people started to understand WHY I programmaed like that as those things became common to other languages. Dijkstra's article focused on the way goto was used at that time

Comment: For bonus points, you should put `int` in front of `F_OO();` in main() and employ the most vexing parse.  Maybe wrapped in a define...

Comment: -1 for making a very large argument why Dijkstra's remark is not applicable, while forgetting to show what the advantages of `goto` actually are (which is the question posted)

Comment: ^ like owlstead said. I did not -1, but the OP was asking WHEN goto is useful in a structured language. This doesn't give any examples of when goto is useful, nor even link to such examples. Also, re point #3: that depends on the language, and on how one weighs trade-offs. Usually a "better" solution is to factor out small functions, so that no single function has a complex control-flow. The one remaining debatable point is whether it is acceptable to use multiple returns in such small functions. A few people instead goto a common return point. Others use flags & testing.

Comment: @MikeSamuel that's shoehorned. Write a protocol decoder with for/while and then with goto...

Comment: @bennnnn, maybe but I don't see how that's relevant to tail-recursion in generated code.

Comment: @MikeSamuel *optimization. IE, avoiding branch misprediction.

Comment: @bennnn, I don't understand.  Both `goto` and `for (;;;)` compile to unconditional jumps.  How is one better w.r.t. branch prediction?

Comment: @MikeSamuel, do you mean `for (;;)` ?

Comment: @tgm1024, Yes, I meant `for (;;)`.

Comment: "'bated".  It's a contraction of "abated".  At least, if you want your writing to appear to be set in a context as old as that of "GoTo Considered Harmful".

Answer (score 171):

Obeying best practices blindly is not a best practice.  The idea of avoiding `goto` statements as one's primary form of flow control is to avoid producing unreadable spaghetti code.  If used sparingly in the right places, they can sometimes be the simplest, clearest way of expressing an idea.  Walter Bright, the creator of the Zortech C++ compiler and the D programming language, uses them frequently, but judiciously.  Even with the `goto` statements, his code is still perfectly readable.

Bottom line:  Avoiding `goto` for the sake of avoiding `goto` is pointless.  What you really want to avoid is producing unreadable code.  If your `goto`-laden code is readable, then there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 43):

Well, there's one thing that's always worse than `goto's`; strange use of other programflow operators to avoid a goto:

**Examples:**

```
    // 1
    try{
      ...
      throw NoErrorException;
      ...
    } catch (const NoErrorException& noe){
      // This is the worst
    } 


    // 2
    do {
      ...break; 
      ...break;
    } while (false);


    // 3
    for(int i = 0;...) { 
      bool restartOuter = false;
      for (int j = 0;...) {
        if (...)
          restartOuter = true;
      if (restartOuter) {
        i = -1;
      }
    }

etc
etc
```

Comment: `do{}while(false)` I think can be considered idiomatic. You are not allowed to disagree :D

Comment: @trinithis: If it's "idiomatic", that's only because of the anti-goto cult.  If you look closely at it, you'll realize it's just a way of saying `goto after_do_block;` without actually saying that.  Otherwise...a "loop" that runs exactly one time?  I'd call that abuse of control structures.

Comment: @ThomasEding Eding There's one exception to your point. If you ever done some C/C++ programming and had to use #define, you would know, that do{}while(0) is one of standards for encapsulating multiple lines of code. For example: _#define do{memcpy(a,b,1); something++;}while(0)_ is safer and better than _#define memcpy(a,b,1); something++_

Comment: @Ignas2526 You've just very nicely shown how `#define`s are many, many times much worse than using `goto` once in a while :D

Comment: @Luaan Really? Well #define and goto are different things for different purposes. Define works perfectly fine when you use it for constants. In some applications, using define for code is the only way. Seems like you haven't grown up yet enough to see such applications.

Comment: @Ignas2526 That's very much possible. It still doesn't make it a good practice, even if it's supposedly the only way :)

Comment: +1 for a good list of ways that people try to avoid gotos, to an extreme; I've seen mentions of such techniques elsewhere, but this is a great, succinct, list. Pondering why, in the past 15 years, my team has never needed any of those techniques, nor used gotos. Even in a client/server application with hundreds of thousands of lines of code, by multiple programmers. C#, java, PHP, python, javascript. Client, server, and app code. Not bragging, nor proselytizing for one position, just truly curious why some people encounter situations that beg for gotos as clearest solution, and others don't...

Comment: FYI, the main technique we use for avoiding both convoluted control flow and gotos, is a willingness to break into many little routines, and allowing those routines to contain multiple returns (because they are small enough to be easily understood, debugged, and modified). Secondary solution is use of flags to modify loop control. But I've never seen it degenerate into one of the forms you show there. And I accept that some people would prefer gotos to multiple returns, even in the simplest routines.

Comment: @Ignas2526 even using `do { } while(0)` is a very ugly thing. Why not only use `{ }`? I see a bunch of C codes with many ugly things uncommented.

Answer (score 35):

Since `goto` makes reasoning about program flow hard<sup>1</sup> (aka. “spaghetti code”), `goto` is generally only used to compensate for missing features: The use of `goto` may actually be acceptable, but only if the language doesn't offer a more structured variant to obtain the same goal. Take Doubt's example:

> The rule with goto that we use is that goto is okay to for jumping forward to a single exit cleanup point in a function.

This is true – but only if the language doesn't allow structured exception handling with cleanup code (such as RAII or `finally`), which does the same job better (as it is specially built for doing it), or when there's a good reason not to employ structured exception handling (but you will never have this case except at a very low level).

In most other languages, the only acceptable use of `goto` is to exit nested loops. And even there it is almost always better to lift the outer loop into an own method and use `return` instead.

Other than that, `goto` is a sign that not enough thought has gone into the particular piece of code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Modern languages which support `goto` implement some restrictions (e.g. `goto` may not jump into or out of functions) but the problem fundamentally remains the same.

Incidentally, the same is of course also true for other language features, most notably exceptions. And there are usually strict rules in place to only use these features where indicated, such as the rule not to use exceptions to control non-exceptional program flow.

Comment: Just curious here, but what about the case of using gotos for clean up code. By clean-up, I mean, not only deallocation of memory, but also, say error logging. 

I was reading through a bunch of posts, and apparently, no one writes code that prints logs.. hmm?!

Comment: shiva: I'm not sure where you see a benefit of `goto` here. RAII and structured error handling are powerful mechanisms to facilitate logging. Admittedly, it's not done nearly enough because it *always* clutters the code.

Comment: The admonition against goto comes from the structured programming era, where early returns were also considered evil. Moving nested loops into a function trades one "evil" for another, and creates a function that has no real reason to exist (outside of "it allowed me to avoid using a goto!"). It's true that goto is the single most powerful tool for producing spaghetti code if used without constraints, but this is a perfect application for it; it simplifies the code. Knuth argued for this usage, and Dijkstra said "Don't fall into the trap of believing that I am terribly dogmatical about goto".

Comment: `finally`? So using exceptions for things other than error handling is good but using `goto` is bad? I think *exceptions* are quite aptly named.

Comment: @Christian `finally` is for cleanup after an exception was thrown. How is that abuse?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm just saying that there are cases where RAII isn't a good solution and it's cleanup but not error handling. Then using exceptions, just to avoid `goto` is worse style than `goto` itself IMHO. Using exceptions for error handling is just the thing to do of course, I guess nobody would argue against that.

Comment: @Christian Well you’re simply wrong then. There’s a vast consensus that RAII is perfectly suited for this. In fact, many modern C++ idioms use it. You seem under the impression that you need to throw an exception to make RAII usable but that’s of course wrong. You’d simply return early from most functions and let RAII take care of cleanup – exceptions aren’t involved in that.

Comment: I appreciate your German directness but I believe a bit more caution in your assessment of what I actually meant would have been appropriate. I didn't confuse RAII and exceptions and I didn't imply that RAII isn't anything but perfect for most cases. All I wanted to say in my last comment was what this answer sums up nicely http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507873/1050373.

Comment: @Christian That answer says to use RAII in exactly the way I outlined. I wouldn’t dream of using exceptions in that scenario (unless of course they actually made semantic sense). I cannot imagine a situation where I’d ever reach point 3 in that answer – I’m pretty confident that I never have, for one thing. If I ever do I promise you to use `goto` instead of the `do…while` construct. ;-)

Comment: For instance Java also has labeled breaks, which can be used instead of `goto` for getting out of nested loops. Labeled breaks are not pretty either, but they are less controversial than `goto` statements.

Comment: @shiva: in what language?  Try/Catch/Finally in C# (or other lazy GC'd language) covers every case I am aware of. In C++ (or other language with tight memory control), RAII is the accepted solution.

Comment: @Mud: in the cases that I encounter (on a daily basis), creating a function "that has no real reason to exist" **is** the best solution. Reason: it removes detail from the top-level function, such that the result has easy-to-read control flow. I don't personally encounter situations where a goto produces the most readable code. On the other hand, I use multiple returns, in simple functions, where someone else might prefer to goto a single exit point. I would love to see counter-examples where goto is more readable than refactoring into well-named functions.

Comment: @Mud: to clarify how I refactor: Typically the most readable style is to replace complicated tests by a single function, and complicated actions by another function. This might convert a  massive function into MANY little pieces -- but the top-level method should be easy to read, and shouldn't need any gotos. All the gotos have become condition tests, or else extra returns in one of the little pieces. (And if you preferred gotos WITHIN one of those little pieces, to avoid multiple returns, that is a defensible style.) I don't know any situations that don't fit this approach.

Comment: Wow. This is an old thread! @KonradRudolph There are several answers in this thread that answer your questions better than I can. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24476/11018
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360087/11018

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve C was the language I was talking about. Then again that was 5 years ago! :)

Comment: @shiva I didn’t actually ask a question. The threads you’ve linked reveal nothing new. In particular, (1) exiting functions are already mentioned in my answer; (2) exiting nested loops is already mentioned in my answer; (3) speed improvement is a questionable argument. I’m aware of Knuth’s essay on the subject, and his examples of a case where `goto` is the fastest solution. But in practice I haven’t encountered a situation yet where `goto` improved performance (and I *have* written my share of high-performance code).

Answer (score 30):

In **C#** [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement [doest not allow fall-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336815.aspx). So [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) is used to transfer control to a specific switch-case label or the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5.aspx) label.

For example:

```
switch(value)
{
  case 0:
    Console.WriteLine("In case 0");
    goto case 1;
  case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("In case 1");
    goto case 2;
  case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("In case 2");
    goto default;
  default:
    Console.WriteLine("In default");
    break;
}
```

*Edit: There is one exception on "no fall-through" rule. Fall-through is allowed if a case statement has no code.*

Comment: Switch fall-through is supported in .NET 2.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Only if the case doesn't have a code body.  If it does have code then you must use the goto keyword.

Comment: This answer is so funny - C# removed fall-through because many see it as harmful, and this example uses goto (also seen as harmful by many) to revive the original, supposedly harmful, behaviour, BUT the overall result is actually less harmful (because the code makes it clear that the fallthrough is intentional!).

Comment: Just because a keyword is written with the letters G-O-T-O does not make it a goto. This presented case is not a goto. It is a switch statement construct for fallthrough. Then again, I don't really know C# very well, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, in this case it's a bit more than fall-through (because you can say `goto case 5:` when you're in case 1). It seems like Konrad Rudolph's answer is correct here: `goto` is compensating for a missing feature (and is less clear than the real feature would be). If what we really want is fall-through, perhaps the best default would be no fall-through, but something like `continue` to explicitly request it.

Comment: Of course, many programmers consider switch fall-through as evil as goto, for the same reason: it can make code hard to reason about. And I've shamelessly used it to simplify code before. :) Just because a power saw is dangerous doesn't mean you leave it out of your tool kit.

Comment: This **is** a legitimate example of a situation where goto **might** be appropriate. **However**, in the real-world cases that I have encountered over the past ten years of C# coding, I've never encountered a situation where I would consider this the cleanest solution. **Alternative #1:**  Call common functions. `case 0: f0(); f1(); f2();`, `case 1: f1(); f2();` etc.  **Alternative #2:** a series of ifs:  `if (value==0) f(0);`, `if (value==0 || value==1) f(1);` etc.  Granted, in this contrived example the gotos might be clearer. But in real-life situations, I doubt it.

Answer (score 16):

I've written more than a few lines of assembly language over the years. Ultimately, every high level language compiles down to gotos. Okay, call them "branches" or "jumps" or whatever else, but they're gotos. Can anyone write goto-less assembler?

Now sure, you can point out to a Fortran, C or BASIC programmer that to run riot with gotos is a recipe for spaghetti bolognaise. The answer however is not to avoid them, but to use them carefully.

A knife can be used to prepare food, free someone, or kill someone. Do we do without knives through fear of the latter? Similarly the goto: used carelessly it hinders, used carefully it helps.

Comment: Perhaps you want to read why I believe this is fundamentally wrong at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful#47476

Comment: Anybody who advances the "it all compiles down to JMP anyway!" argument basically doesn't understand the point behind programming in a higher level language.

Comment: All you really need is subtract-and-branch. Everything else is for convenience or performance.

Answer (score 15):

`#ifdef TONGUE_IN_CHEEK`

Perl has a `goto` that allows you to implement poor-man's tail calls. :-P

```
sub factorial {
    my ($n, $acc) = (@_, 1);
    return $acc if $n < 1;
    @_ = ($n - 1, $acc * $n);
    goto &factorial;
}
```

`#endif`

Okay, so that has nothing to do with C's `goto`. More seriously, I agree with the other comments about using `goto` for cleanups, or for implementing [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device), or the like. It's all about using, not abusing.

(The same comment can apply to `longjmp`, exceptions, [`call/cc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/call-with-current-continuation), and the like---they have legitimate uses, but can easily be abused. For example, throwing an exception purely to escape a deeply-nested control structure, under completely non-exceptional circumstances.)

Comment: I think this is the only reason to use goto in Perl.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [When To Use Goto When Programming in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/goto.html):

> Although the use of goto is almost always bad programming practice (surely you can find a better way of doing XYZ), there are times when it really isn't a bad choice. Some might even argue that, when it is useful, it's the best choice.
>
> Most of what I have to say about goto really only applies to C. If you're using C++, there's no sound reason to use goto in place of exceptions. In C, however, you don't have the power of an exception handling mechanism, so if you want to separate out error handling from the rest of your program logic, and you want to avoid rewriting clean up code multiple times throughout your code, then goto can be a good choice.

What do I mean? You might have some code that looks like this:

```
int big_function()
{
    /* do some work */
    if([error])
    {
        /* clean up*/
        return [error];
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        /* clean up*/
        return [error];
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        /* clean up*/
        return [error];
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        /* clean up*/
        return [error];
    }
    /* clean up*/
    return [success];
}
```

This is fine until you realize that you need to change your cleanup code. Then you have to go through and make 4 changes. Now, you might decide that you can just encapsulate all of the cleanup into a single function; that's not a bad idea. But it does mean that you'll need to be careful with pointers -- if you plan to free a pointer in your cleanup function, there's no way to set it to then point to NULL unless you pass in a pointer to a pointer. In a lot of cases, you won't be using that pointer again anyway, so that may not be a major concern. On the other hand, if you add in a new pointer, file handle, or other thing that needs cleanup, then you'll need to change your cleanup function again; and then you'll need to change the arguments to that function.

By using `goto`, it will be

```
int big_function()
{
    int ret_val = [success];
    /* do some work */
    if([error])
    {
        ret_val = [error];
        goto end;
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        ret_val = [error];
        goto end;
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        ret_val = [error];
        goto end;
    }
    /* do some more work */
    if([error])
    {
        ret_val = [error];
        goto end;
    }
end:
    /* clean up*/
    return ret_val;
}
```

The benefit here is that your code following end has access to everything it will need to perform cleanup, and you've managed to reduce the number of change points considerably. Another benefit is that you've gone from having multiple exit points for your function to just one; there's no chance you'll accidentally return from the function without cleaning up.

Moreover, since goto is only being used to jump to a single point, it's not as though you're creating a mass of spaghetti code jumping back and forth in an attempt to simulate function calls. Rather, goto actually helps write more structured code.

---

**In a word, `goto` should always be used sparingly, and as a last resort -- but there is a time and a place for it. The question should be not "do you have to use it" but "is it the best choice" to use it.**

Comment: The CPython [`/Modules`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/a4ac14faa5c2be433738dfbbed14b0eaa1a2399e/Modules) directory has thousands of uses of `goto`. It's almost entirely for error handling, `goto bail;`, `goto error`, `goto Fail`, `goto nomemory`, `goto invalid_string_error`, `goto exit`, `goto overflow`, `goto finally`, `goto cleanup`, `goto abort` are a sampling of the labels.

Answer (score 8):

The rule with goto that we use is that goto is okay to for jumping forward to a single exit cleanup point in a function. In really complex functions we relax that rule to allow other jump forwards. In both cases we are avoiding deeply nested if statements that often occur with error code checking, which helps readability and maintance.

Comment: I could see something like that being useful in a language like C. However, when you have the power of C++ constructors / destructors, that's generally not so useful.

Comment: *" In really complex functions we relax that rule to allow other jump forwards"* Without an example, that sounds like, if you are making complex functions even more complex by using jumps. Wouldn't be the "better" approach be to refactor and split those complex functions?

Comment: This was the last purpose for which I used goto. I don't miss goto in Java, because it has try-finally that can do the same job.

Answer (score 8):

I find it funny that some people will go as far as to give a list of cases where goto is acceptable, saying that all other uses are unacceptable. Do you really think that you know every case where goto is the best choice for expressing an algorithm?

To illustrate, I'll give you an example that no one here has shown yet:

Today I was writing code for inserting an element in a hash table. The hash table is a cache of previous calculations which can be overwritten at will (affecting performance but not correctness).

Each bucket of the hash table has 4 slots, and I have a bunch of criteria to decide which element to overwrite when a bucket is full. Right now this means making up to three passes through a bucket, like this:

```
// Overwrite an element with same hash key if it exists
for (add_index=0; add_index < ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET; add_index++)
  if (slot_p[add_index].hash_key == hash_key)
    goto add;

// Otherwise, find first empty element
for (add_index=0; add_index < ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET; add_index++)
  if ((slot_p[add_index].type == TT_ELEMENT_EMPTY)
    goto add;

// Additional passes go here...

add:
// element is written to the hash table here
```

Now if I didn't use goto, what would this code look like?

Something like this:

```
// Overwrite an element with same hash key if it exists
for (add_index=0; add_index < ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET; add_index++)
  if (slot_p[add_index].hash_key == hash_key)
    break;

if (add_index >= ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET) {
  // Otherwise, find first empty element
  for (add_index=0; add_index < ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET; add_index++)
    if ((slot_p[add_index].type == TT_ELEMENT_EMPTY)
      break;
  if (add_index >= ELEMENTS_PER_BUCKET)
   // Additional passes go here (nested further)...
}

// element is written to the hash table here
```

It would look worse and worse if more passes are added, while the version with goto keeps the same indentation level at all times and avoids the use of spurious if statements whose result is implied by the execution of the previous loop.

So there's another case where goto makes the code cleaner and easier to write and understand... I'm sure there are many more, so don't pretend to know all the cases where goto is useful, dissing any good ones that you couldn't think of.

Comment: In the example you gave, I'd prefer to refactor that pretty significantly. In general, I try to avoid one-liner comments that say what the next chunk of code is doing. Instead, I break that out into its own function that is named similar to the comment. If you were to make such a transformation, then this function would give a high level overview of what the function is doing, and each of the new functions would state how you do each step. I feel that much more important than any opposition to `goto` is having each function be at the same level of abstraction. That it avoids `goto` is a bonus.

Comment: You haven't really explained how adding more functions gets rid of the goto, the multiple indentation levels and spurious if statements...

Comment: It would look something like this, using standard container notation: `container::iterator it = slot_p.find(hash_key); if (it != slot_p.end()) it->overwrite(hash_key); else it = slot_p.find_first_empty();` I find that sort of programming much easier to read. Each function in this case could be written as a pure function, which is much easier to reason about. The main function now explains what the code does just by the name of the functions, and then if you want, you can look at their definitions to find out how it does it.

Comment: The fact that anyone has to give examples, of how certain algorithms should naturally use a goto - is a sad reflection on how little algorithmic thinking goes on today!!  Of course, @Ricardo's example is (one of many) perfect examples of where goto is elegant and obvious.

Answer (score 8):

The most thoughtful and thorough discussion of goto statements, their legitimate uses, and alternative constructs that can be used in place of "virtuous goto statements" but can be abused as easily as goto statements, is Donald Knuth's article "[Structured Programming with goto Statements](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/360000/356640/p261-knuth.pdf?ip=216.239.45.90&id=356640&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35B1A2F845BC253D7142744268AEEA849682EF35FD85DCD9E9&CFID=389578097&CFTOKEN=41499978&__acm__=1388680055_c32b25b15539895440b9901c898a9dec)", in the December 1974 Computing Surveys (volume 6, no. 4. pp. 261 - 301).

Not surprisingly, some aspects of this 39-year old paper are dated: Orders-of-magnitude increases in processing power make some of Knuth's performance improvements unnoticeable for moderately sized problems, and new programming-language constructs have been invented since then. (For example, try-catch blocks subsume Zahn's Construct, although they are rarely used in that way.) But Knuth covers all sides of the argument, and should be required reading before anyone rehashes the issue yet again.

Answer (score 7):

One of the reasons goto is bad, besides coding style is that you can use it to create *overlapping*, but *non-nested* loops:

```
loop1:
  a
loop2:
  b
  if(cond1) goto loop1
  c
  if(cond2) goto loop2
```

This would create the bizarre, but possibly legal flow-of-control structure where a sequence like (a, b, c, b, a, b, a, b, ...) is possible, which makes compiler hackers unhappy. Apparently there are a number of clever optimization tricks that rely on this type of structure not occuring. (I should check my copy of the dragon book...) The result of this might (using some compilers) be that other optimizations aren't done for code that contains `goto`s.

It might be useful if you *know* it just, "oh, by the way", happens to persuade the compiler to emit faster code. Personally, I'd prefer to try to explain to the compiler about what's probable and what's not before using a trick like goto, but arguably, I might also try `goto` before hacking assembler.

Comment: Well...takes me back to the days of programming FORTRAN in a financial information company. In 2007.

Comment: Any language structure can be abused in ways that render it unreadable or poorly-performing.

Comment: @JUST: The point is not about readability, or poor performance, but assumptions and guarantees about the flow-of-control graph. Any abuse of goto would be for *increased* performance (or readability).

Comment: I'd argue one of the reasons `goto` is *useful* is that it allows you to construct loops like this, that would require a bunch of logical contortions otherwise.  I'd further argue that if the optimizer doesn't know how to rewrite this, then *good*.  A loop like this shouldn't be done for performance or readability, but because that is exactly the order in which things need to happen.  In which case i wouldn't particularly *want* the optimizer screwing around with it.

Comment: Many problem domains have considerable "don't-care" aspects of their behavior such that they could fit a partial-overlap loop design, but could also fit a conventional nested-loop design.  Historically, in goto-based languages such things were often written with partial-overlap style even when a nested-loop design would have been just as good a fit and required about the same amount of code.  That's one of the reasons for the animus against gotos.  On the other hand, for some of the rare problem domains where quirky loop behavior is a key aspect of what the code is supposed to do, ...

Comment: ...a straightforward translation of the required algorithm into GOTO-based code may be much easier to validate than a mess of flag variables and abused looping constructs.

Answer (score 6):

Some say there is no reason for goto in C++. Some say that in 99% cases there are better alternatives. **This is not reasoning, just irrational impressions.** Here's a solid example where goto leads to a nice code, something like enhanced do-while loop:

```
int i;

PROMPT_INSERT_NUMBER:
  std::cout << "insert number: ";
  std::cin >> i;
  if(std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    goto PROMPT_INSERT_NUMBER;          
  }

std::cout << "your number is " << i;
```

Compare it to goto-free code:

```
int i;

bool loop;
do {
  loop = false;
  std::cout << "insert number: ";
  std::cin >> i;
  if(std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    loop = true;          
  }
} while(loop);

std::cout << "your number is " << i;
```

I see these differences:

- nested `{}` block is needed (albeit `do {...} while` looks more familiar)
- extra `loop` variable is needed, used in four places
- it takes longer time to read and understand the work with the `loop`
- the `loop` does not hold any data, it just controls the flow of the execution, which is less comprehensible than simple label

There is another example

```
void sort(int* array, int length) {
SORT:
  for(int i=0; i<length-1; ++i) if(array[i]>array[i+1]) {
    swap(data[i], data[i+1]);
    goto SORT; // it is very easy to understand this code, right?
  }
}
```

Now let's get rid of the "evil" goto:

```
void sort(int* array, int length) {
  bool seemslegit;
  do {
    seemslegit = true;
    for(int i=0; i<length-1; ++i) if(array[i]>array[i+1]) {
      swap(data[i], data[i+1]);
      seemslegit = false;
    }
  } while(!seemslegit);
}
```

You see it is the same type of using goto, it is well structured pattern and it is not forward goto as many promote as the only recommended way. Surely you want to avoid "smart" code like this:

```
void sort(int* array, int length) {
  for(int i=0; i<length-1; ++i) if(array[i]>array[i+1]) {
    swap(data[i], data[i+1]);
    i = -1; // it works, but WTF on the first glance
  }
}
```

The point is that goto can be easily misused, but goto itself is not to blame. Note that label has function scope in C++, so it does not pollute global scope like in pure assembly, in which *overlapping loops* have its place and are very common - like in the following code for 8051, where 7segment display is connected to P1. The program loops lightning segment around:

```
; P1 states loops
; 11111110 <-
; 11111101  |
; 11111011  |
; 11110111  |
; 11101111  |
; 11011111  |
; |_________|

init_roll_state:
    MOV P1,#11111110b
    ACALL delay
next_roll_state:
    MOV A,P1
    RL A
    MOV P1,A
    ACALL delay
    JNB P1.5, init_roll_state
    SJMP next_roll_state
```

There is another advantage: goto can serve as named loops, conditions and other flows:

```
if(valid) {
  do { // while(loop)

// more than one page of code here
// so it is better to comment the meaning
// of the corresponding curly bracket

  } while(loop);
} // if(valid)
```

Or you can use equivalent goto with indentation, so you don't need comment if you choose the label name wisely:

```
if(!valid) goto NOTVALID;
  LOOPBACK:

// more than one page of code here

  if(loop) goto LOOPBACK;
NOTVALID:;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have come across a situation where a `goto` was a good solution, and I have not seen this example here or anywhere.

I had a switch case with a few cases which all needed to call the same function in the end. I had other cases which all needed to call a different function in the end.

This looked a bit like this:

```
switch( x ) {
    
    case 1: case1() ; doStuffFor123() ; break ;
    case 2: case2() ; doStuffFor123() ; break ;
    case 3: case3() ; doStuffFor123() ; break ;
    
    case 4: case4() ; doStuffFor456() ; break ;
    case 5: case5() ; doStuffFor456() ; break ;
    case 6: case6() ; doStuffFor456() ; break ;
    
    case 7: case7() ; doStuffFor789() ; break ;
    case 8: case8() ; doStuffFor789() ; break ;
    case 9: case9() ; doStuffFor789() ; break ;
}
```

Instead of giving every case a function call, I replaced the `break` by a `goto`. The `goto` jumps to a label which is also inside the switch case.

```
switch( x ) {
    
    case 1: case1() ; goto stuff123 ;
    case 2: case2() ; goto stuff123 ;
    case 3: case3() ; goto stuff123 ;
    
    case 4: case4() ; goto stuff456 ;
    case 5: case5() ; goto stuff456 ;
    case 6: case6() ; goto stuff456 ;
    
    case 7: case7() ; goto stuff789 ;
    case 8: case8() ; goto stuff789 ;
    case 9: case9() ; goto stuff789 ;
    
    stuff123: doStuffFor123() ; break ;
    stuff456: doStuffFor456() ; break ;
    stuff789: doStuffFor789() ; break ;
}
```

cases 1 through 3 all must call `doStuffFor123()` and similarly cases 4 through 6 had to call `doStuffFor456()` etc.

In my opinion, gotos are perfectly fine if you use them correctly. In the end, any code is as clear as people write it. With gotos one can make spaghetti code, but that does not mean that gotos are the cause of the spaghetti code. That cause is us; programmers. I can also create spaghetti code with functions if I want to. The same goes for macros as well.

Answer (score 4):

In a Perl module, you occasionally want to create subroutines or closures on the fly. The thing is, that once you have created the subroutine, how do you get to it. You could just call it, but then if the subroutine uses [`caller()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) it won't be as helpful as it could be. That is where the [`goto &subroutine`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) variation can be helpful.

#### Here is a quick example:

```perl
sub AUTOLOAD{
  my($self) = @_;
  my $name = $AUTOLOAD;
  $name =~ s/.*:://;

  *{$name} = my($sub) = sub{
    # the body of the closure
  }

  goto $sub;

  # nothing after the goto will ever be executed.
}
```

---

You can also use this form of `goto` to provide a rudimentary form of tail-call optimization.

```perl
sub factorial($){
  my($n,$tally) = (@_,1);

  return $tally if $n <= 1;

  $tally *= $n--;
  @_ = ($n,$tally);
  goto &factorial;
}
```

( In [Perl 5 version 16](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#__SUB__) that would be better written as [`goto __SUB__;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) )

There is a module that will import a [`tail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Call::Tail) modifier and one that will import [`recur`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Call::Recur) if you don't like using this form of [`goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html).

```perl
use Sub::Call::Tail;
sub AUTOLOAD {
  ...
  tail &$sub( @_ );
}

use Sub::Call::Recur;
sub factorial($){
  my($n,$tally) = (@_,1);

  return $tally if $n <= 1;
  recur( $n-1, $tally * $n );
}
```

---

#### Most of the other reasons to use `goto` are better done with other keywords.

Like [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html)ing a bit of code:

```perl
LABEL: ;
...
goto LABEL if $x;
```

```perl
{
  ...
  redo if $x;
}
```

Or going to the [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) of a bit of code from multiple places:

```perl
goto LABEL if $x;
...
goto LABEL if $y;
...
LABEL: ;
```

```perl
{
  last if $x;
  ...
  last if $y
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1) The most common use of goto that I know of is emulating exception handling in languages that don't offer it, namely in C. (The code given by Nuclear above is just that.) Look at the Linux source code and you'll see a bazillion gotos used that way; there were about 100,000 gotos in Linux code according to a quick survey conducted in 2013: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/894. Goto usage is even mentioned in the Linux coding style guide: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle. Just like object-oriented programming is emulated using structs populated with function pointers, goto has its place in C programming. So who is right: Dijkstra or Linus (and all Linux kernel coders)? It's theory vs. practice basically.

There is however the usual gotcha for not having compiler-level support and checks for common constructs/patterns: it's easier to use them wrong and introduce bugs without compile-time checks. Windows and Visual C++ but in C mode offer exception handling via SEH/VEH for this very reason: exceptions are useful even outside OOP languages, i.e. in a procedural language. But the compiler can't always save your bacon, even if it offers syntactic support for exceptions in the language. Consider as example of the latter case the famous Apple SSL "goto fail" bug, which just duplicated one goto with disastrous consequences (https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html):

```
if (something())
  goto fail;
  goto fail; // copypasta bug
printf("Never reached\n");
fail:
  // control jumps here
```

You can have exactly the same bug using compiler-supported exceptions, e.g. in C++:

```
struct Fail {};

try {
  if (something())
    throw Fail();
    throw Fail(); // copypasta bug
  printf("Never reached\n");
}
catch (Fail&) {
  // control jumps here
}
```

But both variants of the bug can be avoided if the compiler analyzes and warns you about unreachable code. For example compiling with Visual C++ at the /W4 warning level finds the bug in both cases. Java for instance forbids unreachable code (where it can find it!) for a pretty good reason: it's likely to be a bug in the average Joe's code. As long as the goto construct doesn't allow targets that the compiler can't easily figure out, like gotos to computed addresses(**), it's not any harder for the compiler to find unreachable code inside a function with gotos than using Dijkstra-approved code.

(**) Footnote: Gotos to computed line numbers are possible in some versions of Basic, e.g. GOTO 10*x where x is a variable. Rather confusingly, in Fortran "computed goto" refers to a construct that is equivalent to a switch statement in C. Standard C doesn't allow computed gotos in the language, but only gotos to statically/syntactically declared labels. GNU C however has an extension to get the address of a label (the unary, prefix && operator) and also allows a goto to a variable of type void*. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html for more on this obscure sub-topic. The rest of this post ins't concerned with that obscure GNU C feature.

Standard C (i.e. not computed) gotos are not usually the reason why unreachable code can't be found at compile time. The usual reason is logic code like the following. Given

```
int computation1() {
  return 1;
}

int computation2() {
  return computation1();
}
```

It's just as hard for a compiler to find unreachable code in any of the following 3 constructs:

```
void tough1() {
  if (computation1() != computation2())
    printf("Unreachable\n");
}

void tough2() {
  if (computation1() == computation2())
    goto out;
  printf("Unreachable\n");
out:;
}

struct Out{};

void tough3() {
  try {
    if (computation1() == computation2())
      throw Out();
    printf("Unreachable\n");
  }
  catch (Out&) {
  }
}
```

(Excuse my brace-related coding style, but I tried to keep the examples as compact as possible.)

Visual C++ /W4 (even with /Ox) fails to find unreachable code in any of these, and as you probably know the problem of finding unreachable code is undecidable in general. (If you don't believe me about that: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2006/OptComp/slides/lecture02.pdf)

As a related issue, the C goto can be used to emulate exceptions only inside the body of a function. The standard C library offers a setjmp() and longjmp() pair of functions for emulating non-local exits/exceptions, but those have some serious drawbacks compared to what other languages offer. The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h explains fairly well this latter issue. This function pair also works on Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2ez4as.aspx), but hardly anyone uses them there because SEH/VEH is superior. Even on Unix, I think setjmp and longjmp are very seldom used.

2) I think the second most common use of goto in C is implementing multi-level break or multi-level continue, which is also a fairly uncontroversial use case. Recall that Java doesn't allow goto label, but allows break label or continue label. According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/simple-142616.html, this is actually the most common use case of gotos in C (90% they say), but in my subjective experience, system code tends to use gotos for error handling more often. Perhaps in scientific code or where the OS offers exception handling (Windows) then multi-level exits are the dominant use case. They don't really give any details as to the context of their survey.

Edited to add: it turns out these two use patterns are found in the C book of Kernighan and Ritchie, around page 60 (depending on edition). Another thing of note is that both use cases involve only forward gotos. And it turns out that MISRA C 2012 edition (unlike the 2004 edition) now permits gotos, as long as they are only forward ones.

Comment: Right. The "elephant in the room" is that the Linux kernel, for goodness sake, as one example of a world-critical code base - is loaded with goto. Of course it is. Obviously. The "anti-goto-meme" is just a curiosity from decades ago.  OF COURSE, there are a number of things in programming (notably "statics", indeed "globals" and for example "elseif") which can be abused by non-professionals.  So, if you're kid cousin is learnin 2 program, you tell them "oh don't use globals" and "never use elseif".

Comment: The goto fail bug has nothing to do with goto. The problem is caused by the if statement without braces afterward. Just about any statement copy pasted twice there would have caused a problem. I consider that type of naked braceless if to be much more harmful than goto.

Answer (score 3):

> If so, why?

C has no multi-level/labelled break, and not all control flows can be easily modelled with C's iteration and decision primitives.  gotos go a long way towards redressing these flaws.

Sometimes it's clearer to use a flag variable of some kind to effect a kind of pseudo-multi-level break, but it's not always superior to the goto (at least a goto allows one to easily determine where control goes to, unlike a flag variable), and sometimes you simply don't want to pay the performance price of flags/other contortions to avoid the goto.

libavcodec is a performance-sensitive piece of code. Direct expression of the control flow is probably a priority, because it'll tend to run better.

Answer (score 2):

I find the do{} while(false) usage utterly revolting. It is conceivable might convince me it is necessary in some odd case, but never that it is clean sensible code.

If you must do some such loop, why not make the dependence on the flag variable explicit?

```
for (stepfailed=0 ; ! stepfailed ; /*empty*/)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `/*empty*/` be `stepfailed = 1`? In any case, how is this better than a `do{}while(0)`? In both, you need to `break` out of it (or in yours `stepfailed = 1; continue;`). Seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2):

The GOTO can be used, of course, but there is one more important thing than the code style, or if the code is or not readable that you must have in mind when you use it: **the code inside may not be as robust as you think**.

For instance, look at the following two code snippets:

```
If A <> 0 Then A = 0 EndIf
Write("Value of A:" + A)
```

An equivalent code with GOTO

```
If A == 0 Then GOTO FINAL EndIf
   A = 0
FINAL:
Write("Value of A:" + A)
```

The first thing we think is that the result of both bits of code will be that "Value of A: 0" (we suppose an execution without parallelism, of course)

That's not correct: in the first sample, A will always be 0, but in the second sample (with the GOTO statement) A might not be 0. Why?

The reason is because from another point of the program I can insert a `GOTO FINAL` without controlling the value of A.

This example is very obvious, but as programs get more complicated, the difficulty of seeing those kind of things increases.

Related material can be found into the famous article from Mr. Dijkstra ["A case against the GO TO statement"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF)

Comment: This was often the case in old-school BASIC.  In modern variants, though, you're not allowed to jump into the middle of another function...or in many cases, even past the declaration of a variable.  Basically (pun not intended), modern languages have largely done away with the "unbridled" GOTOs that Dijkstra was talking about...and the only way to use it as he was arguing against, is to commit certain other heinous sins.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It comes in handy for character-wise string processing from time to time.

Imagine something like this printf-esque example:

```
for cur_char, next_char in sliding_window(input_string) {
    if cur_char == '%' {
        if next_char == '%' {
            cur_char_index += 1
            goto handle_literal
        }
        # Some additional logic
        if chars_should_be_handled_literally() {
            goto handle_literal
        }
        # Handle the format
    }
    # some other control characters
    else {
      handle_literal:
        # Complicated logic here
        # Maybe it's writing to an array for some OpenGL calls later or something,
        # all while modifying a bunch of local variables declared outside the loop
    }
}
```

You could refactor that `goto handle_literal` to a function call, but if it's modifying several different local variables, you'd have to pass references to each unless your language supports mutable closures. You'd still have to use a `continue` statement (which is arguably a form of goto) after the call to get the same semantics if your logic makes an else case not work.

I have also used gotos judiciously in lexers, typically for similar cases. You don't need them most of the time, but they're nice to have for those weird cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, use of a label to "goto" from a loop - using a "last" statement, which is similar to break.

This allows better control over nested loops.

The traditional goto *label* is supported too, but I'm not sure there are too many instances where this is the only way to achieve what you want - subroutines and loops should suffice for most cases.

Comment: I think the only form of goto that you would ever use in Perl is `goto &subroutine`. Which starts the subroutine with the current @_, while replacing the current subroutine in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I use goto in the following case:
when needed to return from funcions at different places, and before return some uninitialization needs to be done:

non-goto version:

```
int doSomething (struct my_complicated_stuff *ctx)    
{
    db_conn *conn;
    RSA *key;
    char *temp_data;
    conn = db_connect();  


    if (ctx->smth->needs_alloc) {
      temp_data=malloc(ctx->some_size);
      if (!temp_data) {
        db_disconnect(conn);
        return -1;      
        }
    }

    ...

    if (!ctx->smth->needs_to_be_processed) {
        free(temp_data);    
        db_disconnect(conn);    
        return -2;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(ctx->mutex);

    if (ctx->some_other_thing->error) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->mutex);
        free(temp_data);
        db_disconnect(conn);        
        return -3;  
    }

    ...

    key=rsa_load_key(....);

    ...

    if (ctx->something_else->error) {
         rsa_free(key); 
         pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->mutex);
         free(temp_data);
         db_disconnect(conn);       
         return -4;  
    }

    if (ctx->something_else->additional_check) {
         rsa_free(key); 
         pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->mutex);
         free(temp_data);
         db_disconnect(conn);       
         return -5;  
    }


    pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->mutex);
    free(temp_data);    
    db_disconnect(conn);    
    return 0;     
}
```

goto version:

```
int doSomething_goto (struct my_complicated_stuff *ctx)
{
    int ret=0;
    db_conn *conn;
    RSA *key;
    char *temp_data;
    conn = db_connect();  


    if (ctx->smth->needs_alloc) {
      temp_data=malloc(ctx->some_size);
      if (!temp_data) {
            ret=-1;
           goto exit_db;   
          }
    }

    ...

    if (!ctx->smth->needs_to_be_processed) {
        ret=-2;
        goto exit_freetmp;      
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(ctx->mutex);

    if (ctx->some_other_thing->error) {
        ret=-3;
        goto exit;  
    }

    ...

    key=rsa_load_key(....);

    ...

    if (ctx->something_else->error) {
        ret=-4;
        goto exit_freekey; 
    }

    if (ctx->something_else->additional_check) {
        ret=-5;
        goto exit_freekey;  
    }

exit_freekey:
    rsa_free(key);
exit:    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(ctx->mutex);
exit_freetmp:
    free(temp_data);        
exit_db:
    db_disconnect(conn);    
    return ret;     
}
```

The second version makes it easier, when you need to change something in the deallocation statements (each is used once in the code), and reduces the chance to skip any of them, when adding a new branch. Moving them in a function will not help here, because the deallocation can be done at different "levels".

Comment: This is why we have `finally` blocks in C#

Comment: ^ like @JohnSaunders said. This is an example of "using goto because a language lacks the appropriate control construct". HOWEVER it is a code smell to require MULTIPLE goto points near the return. There is a programming style that is safer (easier to not screw up) **AND** does not require gotos, which works fine even in languages without "finally": design those "clean-up" calls so that they are harmless to do when no clean up is required. Factor everything but the cleanup into a method, which uses the multiple-return design. Call that method, then do the clean-up calls.

Comment: Note that the approach I describe requires an extra level of method call (but only in a language which lacks `finally`). As an alternative, use `goto`s, but to a **common** exit point, which always does **all** the clean-up. But each clean-up method either can handle a value that is null or already clean, or is protected by a conditional test, so skipped when not appropriate.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this is not a code smell; in fact, it is an extremely common pattern in C and is considered one of the most valid ways to use goto. You want me to create 5 methods, each with their own unnecessary if-test, just to handle cleanup from this function? You've now created code AND performance bloat. Or you could just use goto.

Comment: @muusbolla - 1) "create 5 methods" - No. I'm suggesting a *single* method that cleans up any resources that have a non-null value. OR see my alternative, that uses `goto`s that all go to **the same** exit point, which has the same logic (which requires an extra if per resource, as you say). But never mind, when using `C` you are right - whatever the reason the code is in C, its almost certainly a trade-off that favors the most "direct" code. (My suggestion handles complex situations where any given resource may or may not have been allocated. But yeah, overkill in this case.)

Comment: In any language that is higher-level than C, I would do it the way I suggest for one simple reason: multiple `goto`s require any programmer maintaining the code (tracking down an obscure bug or making changes) to carefully examine the gotos to make sure they each go where they should. In this case, making sure they are in the correct order. Contrast this with having a *single* exit point, which tests each resource for non-null, and cleans up the ones that are there. Its a much easier "inspection" to observe that everything is cleaned up. While this is just as true in C, it is more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Use "goto" wherever it makes your code more readable or run faster. Just don't let it turn your code into spaghetti.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with 'goto' and the most important argument of the 'goto-less programming' movement is, that if you use it too frequently your code, although it might behave correctly, becomes unreadable, unmaintainable, unreviewable etc. In 99.99% of the cases 'goto' leads to spaghetti code. Personally, I cannot think of any good reason as to why I would use 'goto'.

Comment: Saying "I cannot think of any reason" in your argument is, formally, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance, although I prefer the terminology "proof by lack of imagination".

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: It’s a logical fallacy only if it’s employed post-hoc. From a language designer’s point of view it may be a valid argument to weigh the cost of including a feature (`goto`). @cschol’s usage is similar: While maybe not designing a language right now, (s)he’s basically evaluating the designer’s effort.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: IMHO, having a language allow `goto` except in contexts where it would bring variables into existence is apt to be cheaper than trying to support every kind of control structure someone might need. Writing code with `goto` may not be as nice as using some other structure, but being able to write such code with `goto` will help avoid "holes in expressiveness"--constructs for which a language is incapable of writing efficient code.

Comment: @supercat I’m afraid we’re from fundamentally different schools of language design. I object to languages being maximally expressive at the price of understandability (or correctness). I’d rather have a restrictive than a permissive language.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I tend to be of the philosophy that it's possible to write unreadable code in any language, and that icky code more often stems from a language's inability to express something nicely, than from its ability to express it poorly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do you know any examples since 1990 where `goto` caused actual trouble? I do not. An obscure example probably exists somewhere but, normally, `goto` is fine. Use it. Enjoy it. It's effective and it's fun. Of all programming constructs likely to be abused, `goto` is comparatively harmless. The `bool` (also harmless) is more likely to be abused. Not harmless (in my opinion) are the lengths to which some programmers will go to avoid `goto` even when `goto` is the right tool for the job, since they have heard that some wise dude named Dijkstra supposedly once recommended against.

Comment: @thb Yes of course I do. It often makes code *much* harder to read and reason about. Virtually every time somebody posts code containing `goto` on the code review site, eliminating the `goto` vastly simplifies the code’s logic.

Comment: @supercat - while I very often agree with your insights, I'm with Konrad on this: I've been tracking language design over 40+ years of programming in a wide variety of languages. I'm 100% behind removing `goto` - not even offering it as an option (in any language higher-level than `C`). We know enough now to never need it. Usually replaced by testing a flag. (In any remaining "holes", factor out a method, call it from several places as needed, and rely on compiler optimizer to inline that code back in. Or add a bool or enum parameters to an existing method.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: If *you* never need it for any of the things that *you* need to do, great.  What makes you think you know about everything that everyone else needs to do?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Perhaps it would be possible for a language to include enough control structures to avoid the need for arbitrary `goto` or otherwise-unnecessary-flags, but I've yet to see any that do.