# Can goto jump across functions without destructors being called?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, language-lawyer, destructor, goto

Is it true that `goto` jumps across bits of code without calling destructors and things?

e.g.

```
void f() {
   int x = 0;
   goto lol;
}

int main() {
   f();
lol:
   return 0;
}
```

Won't `x` be leaked?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258201/will-using-goto-cause-memory-leaks (but I wanted to do it from scratch, cleanly!)

Comment: What does `"Won't x be leaked"` mean? The type of `x` is a built-in data type. Why don't you choose a better example?

Comment: @Nawaz: The example is perfect the way it is. Almost every time I talk to somebody about `goto`, they think that even automatic storage duration variables are somehow "leaked". That you and I know otherwise is completely besides the point.

Comment: @David: I agree that this question makes a lot more sense when the variable has a non-trivial destructor... and I looked in Tomalak's answer and did find such an example.  Furthermore, while an `int` cannot leak, it can *be leaked*.  For example: `void f(void) { new int(5); }` leaks an `int`.

Comment: Why not change the question to something like "In the example given, will the code executation path transfer from f() to main() without clearing the stack and other return-from-function functionality? Would it matter if a destructor needed to be called? Is is the same in C?" Would that both maintain the intent of the question, whilst avoid the possible misconceptions?

Comment: @Jack: Yep, I agree with that (though the language there may have a high entry requirement of knowledge)

Comment: "Can goto jump across functions": No. "... without destructors being called?": irrelevant.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

<sub>**Warning:** This answer pertains to C++ *only*; the rules are quite different in C.</sub>

---

> Won't `x` be leaked?

**No, absolutely not.**

It is a myth that `goto` is some low-level construct that allows you to override C++'s built-in scoping mechanisms. (If anything, it's `longjmp` that may be prone to this.)

Consider the following mechanics that prevent you from doing "bad things" with labels (which includes `case` labels).

---

### 1. Label scope

You can't jump across functions:

```
void f() {
   int x = 0;
   goto lol;
}

int main() {
   f();
lol:
   return 0;
}

// error: label 'lol' used but not defined
```

> `[n3290: 6.1/1]:` [..] The scope of a label is the function in which
>   it appears. [..]

---

### 2. Object initialisation

You can't jump across object initialisation:

```
int main() {
   goto lol;
   int x = 0;
lol:
   return 0;
}

// error: jump to label ‘lol’
// error:   from here
// error:   crosses initialization of ‘int x’
```

If you jump *back* across object initialisation, then [the object's previous "instance" is destroyed](http://codepad.org/iH6V3M03):

```
struct T {
   T() { cout << "*T"; }
  ~T() { cout << "~T"; }
};

int main() {
   int x = 0;

  lol:
   T t;
   if (x++ < 5)
     goto lol;
}

// Output: *T~T*T~T*T~T*T~T*T~T*T~T
```

> `[n3290: 6.6/2]:` [..] Transfer out of a loop, out of a block, or back
>   past an initialized variable with automatic storage duration involves
>   the destruction of objects with automatic storage duration that are in
>   scope at the point transferred from but not at the point transferred
>   to. [..]

You can't jump into the scope of an object, even if it's not explicitly initialised:

```
int main() {
   goto lol;
   {
      std::string x;
lol:
      x = "";
   }
}

// error: jump to label ‘lol’
// error:   from here
// error:   crosses initialization of ‘std::string x’
```

... except for [certain kinds of object](http://codepad.org/lnrnejbk), which the language can handle regardless because they do not require "complex" construction:

```
int main() {
   goto lol;
   {
      int x;
lol:
      x = 0;
   }
}

// OK
```

> `[n3290: 6.7/3]:` It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in
>   a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that
>   jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration
>   is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless
>   the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of
>   these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared
>   without an initializer. [..]

---

### 3. Jumping abides by scope of other objects

Likewise, objects with automatic storage duration [are *not* "leaked" when you `goto` out of their scope](http://codepad.org/HY1JD0Z9):

```
struct T {
   T() { cout << "*T"; }
  ~T() { cout << "~T"; }
};

int main() {
   {
      T t;
      goto lol;
   }

lol:
   return 0;
}

// *T~T
```

> `[n3290: 6.6/2]:` On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects
>   with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in
>   that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.
>   [..]

---

### Conclusion

The above mechanisms ensure that `goto` doesn't let you break the language.

Of course, this doesn't automatically mean that you "should" use `goto` for any given problem, but it *does* mean that it is not nearly as "evil" as the common myth leads people to believe.

Comment: @Ben: Doesn't `[n3290: 18.10/4]:` "The function signature `longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val)` has more restricted behavior in this International Standard. A `setjmp`/`longjmp` call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and `longjmp` by catch
and throw would invoke any non-trivial destructors for any automatic objects." break that?

Comment: You might note that C doesn't prevent all of these dangerous things from happening.

Comment: @Daniel: The question and answer are very specifically about C++, but fair point. Maybe we can have another FAQ dispelling the myth that C and C++ are the same ;)

Comment: For example, `goto lol; int x = 5; lol: printf("%d", x);` gives `warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function`

Comment: @Tomalak: You're right but I think it's fair to point out that something like `goto` which existed in C before C++ was around actually doesn't work exactly the same in C++.

Comment: @Daniel: For the record, this difference with C is made explicit in compatibility section `[n3290: C.1.5]`.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think we're disagreeing here. Many of the answers given on SO are explicitly documented somewhere. I was just making the point that it might be tempting for a C programmer to see this answer and assume that if it works in C++, it should work similarly in C.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think that we're disagreeing either!

Comment: You also might want to add that all these jumping over intialization things are the same for case labels.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I think you just did! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a blurb about what happens if you jump *up* across an initialization.

Comment: @Benjamin: Ooh, I didn't even think about that.

Comment: All above suggestions implemented.

Comment: Wow, I had just assumed C++'s semantics were broken for goto, but they're surprisingly sane! Great answer.