# Is it legal to goto out of try block?

Tags: c++, standards

I have some code that I've inherited from someone very clever where they like to use gotos to leave the try block, jumping completely around the catch blocks.

It definitely works, and I suspect this is legal (I think that the C++ standard says that on exit from a scope, everything gets cleaned up properly, and I assume that applies to whatever the compiler had to do to implement exceptions on my platform).

Is this really legit? It's NOT something I'd ever write (it's too clever by half), but it's clearly working, and I just want to understand why this is OK.

Comment: Call me a little, i guess "new fashioned", but I feel like it is NEVER  ok to use a goto...

Comment: If you have to circumvent the try catch block why use it?

Comment: Here's what happens when you use goto ... https://www.xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Johannes Using a goto to jump out of a try block is - while legal - certainly horrible, horrible style. The only sensible use case for gotos I've seen so far is C code where you want to localize the cleanup. Anything else I've seen so far could've been handled better with modern c++.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Not all dogma is religion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will using `goto` leak variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334952/will-using-goto-leak-variables)

Comment: @DanF never say never...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even more specifically than the C++03 standard's section on jump statements, it says this about try-blocks in the "Exception handling" clause (15/2):

> A goto, break, return, or continue statement can be used to transfer
>   control out of a try block or handler.  When this happens, each
>   variable declared in the try block will be destroyed in the context
>   that directly contains its declaration.

C++11 contains the same wording.

Note however, that's it's *not* OK to jump into a try-block using a `goto` (or `switch`):

> A goto or switch statement shall not be used to transfer control into a try block or into a handler.

Answer (score 12):

It can be legit and it depends on what the code does. For example I have written code that jumps out of a catch block, and it's used in a language's runtime library (for simplicity, the code that uses the runtime library does not implement the itanium exception handling, but is implemented using longjmp/setjmp). The runtime library however, through the C++ exceptions, *does* use it; and a mechanism is needed to cleanly transfer control between them.

```
try {
  doSomethingThatMayFail();
} catch(DiagnosticException&) {
  goto unwind;
}

if(0) {
unwind:
  longjmp(&lastSafePoint, 0);
}
```

I put this into a macro so that it's very convenient to write. The `goto` here is necessary to cleanup resources allocated during exception handling of the diagnostic exception.

As always, don't say "NEVER use this feature". Every use must be carefully thought about, instead.

Comment: This might be a dumb question... but why could you not have `longjmp(&lastSafePoint, 0);` in the catch statement?

Comment: @ahenderson because it would skip the cleanup code that the compiler emits when code leaves the catch block (the object that was thrown by a called function is usually allocated on the heap, and needs to be freed by someone).

Comment: Interesting example, although the original question was about `goto` from inside a `try` block, not a `catch` block.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield indeed. I figure I didn't make this clear enough. Lemme edit.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, FWIW, I was googling specifically for gotoing out of a catch block, and I was very grateful for this answer covering that, too, on a page where I could, thus, get a fairly complete picture.

Answer (score 11):

Standard Says yes, it's legal & well-defined:

### C++2003: 6.6 Jump Statements

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), destructors (12.4) are
>   called for all constructed objects with automatic storage duration
>   (3.7.2) (named objects or temporaries) that are declared in that
>   scope, in the reverse order of their declaration. Transfer out of a
>   loop, out of a block, or back past an initialized variable with
>   automatic storage duration involves the destruction of variables with
>   automatic storage duration that are in scope at the point transferred
>   from but not at the point transferred to. (See 6.7 for transfers into
>   blocks). [Note: However, the program can be terminated (by calling
>   exit() or abort()(18.3), for example) without destroying class objects
>   with automatic storage duration. ]

I choose not to comment on the religious implications of using `goto` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. It's bad code. Don't do it. Don't use `goto`.

Comment: `goto` has its uses, but mixing it in with C++ exception handling is definitely not one of them.

Comment: As someone famous said, "All generalizations are false, including this one". See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/133523/33478) for an argument that `goto` can actually be useful sometimes -- mostly to make up for a feature that's missing from the language you're using. (I'm not arguing that jumping out of a `try` block is a good idea.)

Comment: @Keith About your link: 2. is a good reason for C code but not really necessary in modern C++. 3. can make sense, although I think a simple while loop with the switch inside is just as fine (as you say yourself :) ). 1. can be handled nicer by creating an additional function. So in general I think simply agreeing that gotos are bad isn't such a bad thing in c++ because one gets by just fine without it and well we see what happens if it gets used ;)