# initialization of 'unused' is skipped by 'goto label' - why do I get it for std::string but not for int?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, goto

I bumped against this error in some code, and after some experimenting I stumbled upon this weirdness - I get it for `std::string`, but not for `int`.

For `std::string` I get `error C2362: initialization of 'unused' is skipped by 'goto label'`:

```
{   goto label;
    std::string unused;
label:;
}
```

For `int` **I don't get any error**, however:

```
{   goto label;
    int unused = 10;
label:;
}
```

Why the difference? Is it because `std::string` has a non-trivial destructor?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The same issues occur with `switch`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's not a constructive or helpful comment.

Comment: Related (and contains the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/q/7334952/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That question concerns something totally unrelated: a non-existant `goto` out of a function.

Comment: Advice: Avoid using 'goto' , you should forget that it exists, Because is a bad practice and C++ has enough differents loops that can replace goto.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Did you read the answer? Hint: read the answer. Particularly section 2.

Comment: @DiegoR.Alcantara: Advice: avoid spreading baseless religious mantra when it is not requested. Plus, as James points out, this question is really about jumping to labels, whether you do it using `goto` or not. Do you also hate `switch`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've read Dijkstra's essay, yes. In fact, I was betting someone would make that comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.7` *Declaration statement* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. **A program that jumps<sup>87</sup> from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor**, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).

and provides the following example:

```
void f() {
  // ...
  goto lx; // ill-formed: jump into scope of a
ly:
  X a = 1;
  // ...
lx:
 goto ly; // OK, jump implies destructor
          // call for a followed by construction
          // again immediately following label ly
}
```

Although both cases should generate an error since your are bypassing an initialization in both cases, this however would have been fine:

```
goto label;
      int unused ;
label:
```

So `Visual Studio` is not correct here, both `gcc` and `clang` generate and error for this code, `gcc` says:

```
error:   crosses initialization of 'int unused'
       int unused = 10;
           ^
```

Of course `Visual Studio` can have extension like that as long as they document it but it is not portable to use such an extension, as I pointed out both `clang` and `gcc` generate an error for this.

We can find a rationale for why we don't want to jump across an initialization in [defect report 467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#467) which sought to have the same restriction added for local static variable (*it was rejected*):

> [...]automatic variables, if not explicitly initialized, can have indeterminate (“garbage”) values, including trap representations, [...]

Comment: Except that both of his examples have initialization, and should be illegal.  If the second compiles, it is an error in the compiler.

Comment: @JamesKanze correct, I was just checking out which compiler allowed this ... apparently Visual Studio

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Visual Studio makes the most sensible thing here, I think, because `unused` is well - unused. That the standard doesn't make an exception for this case here is a mistake in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

A compiler error.  Both are illegal.  What is not illegal,
however, is:

```
{
    goto label;
    int unused;
    unused = 10;
label:
    ;
}
```

Both `std::string unused;` and `int unused = 10;` have
initializers (a default constructor in the case of
`std::string`), and you're not allowed to jump around
a definition with an initializer.  Jumping around one without an
initializer is probably allowed avoid breaking code like:

```
switch ( something )
{
    int i;
case 0:
    i = x;
    // ...
    break;

case 1:
    i = y;
    //  ...
    break;
//  ...
}
```

I wouldn't call this good code, but it wouldn't surprise me to
find it in older C, and C++ does try not to break these sort of
things.

Comment: +1: This is why I've gotten into the habit of encasing my `case` "bodies" with new block scopes.