# Cannot understand Behaviour of Static In C and C++

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    goto lb;
    static int a=5;

lb:
    goto b;
    int b=6;

b:
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I save this code with a ".c" file extension, it works well and gives output as 5 followed by a "garbage" value.

But, in C++, it results in an error. I can't understand why there is an error. Can you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the error is? And how you're compiling the program? Or perhaps it's some kind of quiz.

Comment: *How* do you compile? What tool (and version) do you use, and how do you call it?

Comment: `which I have chosen not to share with you for some reason`.. :|

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my psychic debugging skills tell me it has something to do with `goto b;` and skipping the initialization of `int b`

Comment: @Mgetz My psychic compilator agrees.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Totally uncool yo...but extremely amusing :)

Comment: Pfft. A little emphasis to make a point never hurt anyone.

Comment: sorry m new to stackoverflow ...still figuring it out 
i m compiling with codeblocks and getting error for c++
Thank You @LightnessRacesinOrbit i Got it

Comment: Meh - I guess it's not really a static ctor, just an initialization in-line, so it gets missed.

Comment: there is, of course, a reason why you see what you see, but really: _don't use `goto`'s_. ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with statics whatsoever. Your problem can be reproduced with a much smaller piece of code that has no `static` variables in it at all.

[The compilation error is very clear](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2796093108d65b9):

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:12:1: error: jump to label 'b' [-fpermissive]
>  b:
>  ^
> main.cpp:9:10: error:   from here [-fpermissive]
>      goto b;
>           ^
> main.cpp:10:9: error:   crosses initialization of 'int b'
>      int b=6;
>          ^
> ```

C++ has rules against `goto`-jumping across initialisations; this goes hand in hand with its support for classes and objects that are, in general, far more complex than the objects you can create in C.

You should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968/560648).

Answer (score 3):

In C, you're allowed to jump past the initialisation of a variable, and it will remain uninitialised, giving a garbage value (or perhaps other undefined behaviour).

In C++, you're not allowed to jump past the initialisation of a variable. That's because variables in C++ are, in general, more complicated beasts with constructors and destructors. Leaving them uninitialised could leave them in a state where the can't safely be destroyed, making the program go wrong in all manner of ways when they need to be destroyed; and so, instead, the language requires that they are correctly initialised.

At least on my compiler, the error message makes this quite clear:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:17:1: error: jump to label ‘b’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:13:6: error:   from here [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:15:5: error:   crosses initialisation of ‘int b’
```

explaining that it's an error to jump past the initialisation of the variable.

Comment: are you stalking me today ;)

Comment: Btw. do you know if this is a historical relic in C? If I remember right you used to have to declare all variables at the beginning of the scope with older versions, or am I confusing things (I assume this was done to only have to push the stack-pointer once, which most compilers today are still doing but I'm guessing compilers used to do less analysis in the past). edit: found it, [it was C89](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288441/variable-declaration-placement-in-c)

Comment: @PeterT That's an interesting question in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

It is not static it is the goto statement in C++. goto can not cross an initialization in C++.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)