# goto or throw, advantages/disadvantages

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
try
{
  // ...do something... possibly goto error
}
catch (...)
{
}
error:
// ...process error...
```

The problem I face is whether I should use `goto` (when possible) or `throw` to jump to the `error` label. What are the (dis)advantages of both approaches?

EDIT: fixed code to conform to the standard.

Comment: Why do you want goto at all if you can use throw? goto in this situation can make sense if something exception-like should be simulated in C, but only because there is no throw there. (And goto can´t fully replace throw, because latter woirks across functions too.)

Comment: What about this is specific to C++1z, I wonder?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The wording that forbids it exists in C++03 as well (15 (2) instead of 15 (3), but otherwise without changes).

Comment: @Wintermute: That's my point. Nothing about this has changed in over a decade (almost two, actually!)

Comment: The problem is that I call C libraries often (which can't throw at all) and I wanted some protection if somewhere C++ code threw.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, I misread/didn't look at the tags. My bad.

Comment: @Wintermute: Hey no worries

Comment: fixed question to conform to the standard, compiles, I've tested with `gcc`.

Comment: @deviantfan The closest I can imagine to _simulate exceptions_ in c is `setjmp()/longjmp()`, not `goto`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If the code is written in C, then error handling _is_ more complicated; typically, you'll need to return an error code, and propagate it down all of the returns.  If the only worry is handling errors reported by calling into C, the simple solution is to wrap the calls in a C++ function, which converts the C errors into exceptions.  If the worry is that your `extern "C"` will be called by C, then you need to wrap the code in your function in a try/catch block, and convert the exceptions to however the C code expects the error to be reported.

Comment: @user1095108 If you call into a C library, it's not going to throw.  If you pass a callback to the C library, you must ensure that the callback doesn't throw, by wrapping it in a try/catch block.

Comment: @deviantfan Yeah, but `throw` what and for what purpose? As a workaround, so I don't need to use `goto`? Both `throw` and `goto` are not likely to be ever deprecated. When we die and they'll likely still be supported.

Comment: @user1095108 To answer this and the other comment below, it somewhat sounds like you searching not `goto` or `throw`, but `if`.

Comment: @deviantfan No, no. I do `if` in my code, but then I wondered whether to `goto error;` or `throw "";`, if the test for error turns out to be true. Both are very very weird. I hope you agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All concerns about the legality of your idea aside<sup>[1]</sup>, and ignoring the possibility of using `std::current_exception` from C++11 onwards<sup>[2]</sup>, you have no way of handling exceptions in a *meaningful* way from inside a catch-all clause...

... except if you *rethrow* or you don't care at all what kind of exception occurred. But without knowing what exception occurred, what would you do other than kill the process.

The point of handling exceptions in the first place is that there's more to handling than just crashing and burning (or you could just let the compiler call `terminate`, which is easier and less code!). But handling needs to be *meaningful* in some way.
This is why `throw;` as for example used in this common idiom is vastly superior to `goto`:

```
void handler()
{
    try { throw; } catch (foo& f){} catch(bar& b){}  /* ... */
}

// ...
try{ /* ... */ }
catch(...) { handler(); }
```

Yes, `goto` is not inherently evil, but one should only use it in the *very rare* cases where it actually makes code better, more concise, and more readable. This is not one such case.

You might argue that rethrowing is expensive, but that isn't a valid argument. Exceptions occur *exceptionally*, but once you have encountered one, performance is no longer of much concern anyway.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>Pretty sure it's not in accordance with the standard, though I believe that GCC will let you do it anyway, there are some weird extensions on `goto` that let you do funny stuff.
<sup>[2]</sup>While it may be useful for passing exceptions to another thread, it is otherwise pretty ugly and unwieldy compared to the "proper" solution.

Comment: Re: _"What if there is nothing to rethrow?"_: Well if there is nothing to rethrow, that means you didn't throw an exception, so the `catch(...)` clause isn't entered and your handler isn't called either. There is no way of generating an exception without "something". An empty throw-expression is only legal for re-throwing and will immediately call `terminate` otherwise (so you can't do that).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I am wondering what type to throw, if the error comes from C. I can't throw void, but I can throw, say, an int. Both seem strange to me. Currently I do throw "";

Comment: @user1095108: Throwing `int` is discouraged, although I'm not 100% sure why. It certainly is not as expressive as throwing a type with a descriptive name or a class derived from `std::exception` which offers a human-readable string via the `what()` member, but it certainly "works" fine, and I see no hard reason why you _couldn't_ do that to communicate e.g. a fatal error code that came from a C API, if that's all you want. Although of course you can derive from `std::exception` **and** include an integer (and a string description, and other info). It would admittedly be "nicer".

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Now that it's a completely different question, the answer is completely different as well.

The most idiomatic pattern to replace this **for error handling**, I believe, would be to subject the things your C library gives you to RAII with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` using a custom deleter, in which case special handling in the normal case would no longer be necessary for them. Then you can handle errors the usual way:

```
// just for a simple example.
std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> c_obj(malloc(1000), free);

try {
  // Don't use goto, throw.
} catch(...) {
  // handle error here
}
// label not required anymore, cleanup handled by custom deleters. That means
// that free will be called when c_obj is destroyed.
```

I stress that this is for error handling because using `throw` for normal control flow is bad for the same reasons that `goto` is bad: Code becomes more difficult to understand and maintain the more its structure resembles a lump of spaghetti. Were this for normal control flow, I'd tell you to look for ways to restate your problem in a more structured manner.

**Answer to the original question**

Using `goto` in this context is ill-formed as per [except] (15 (3) in C++11, 15 (2) in C++03):

> A `goto` or `switch` statement shall not be used to transfer control into a try block or handler. *[Example:*

```
void f() {
  goto l1; // Ill-formed
  goto l2; // Ill-formed
  try {
    goto l1; // OK
    goto l2; // Ill-formed
    l1: ;
  } catch(...) {
    l2: ;
    goto l1; // Ill-formed
    goto l2; // OK
  }
}
```

> *-- end example]* (...)

Thus your compiler is justified in rejecting such code altogether, and indeed both gcc and clang refuse to compile it.

I suspect that it is forbidden for the same reasons for which it is forbidden to jump past declarations with initialization, which is that being in an exception handler without an exceptions makes no more sense than being in the scope of a variable without the variable. Just like variables with automatic storage duration are handled at the end of the scope (the destructor is called), exceptions may be handled at the end of an exception handler<sup>1</sup>. If either were not there, that would be a problem.

And of course it would also be a problem if your attempted to use them yourself, which is likely another part of the reason that it is forbidden.

<sup>1</sup> *will* be unless you say `throw;`, in which case the exception is handled *in* the handler.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you add a conclusion making clear that no comparison is possible because one of the options is literally impossible.

Comment: fixed the question, sorry

Comment: It' a completely different question now.

Comment: The idea is the same as before. To handle an error from C code, as well as protect against C++ exceptions. Also your answer is very good, please don't delete the standard quote.

Comment: In the code that's in the question now, the `goto` is completely superfluous. It has the same effect as leaving the catch handler the normal way.

Comment: fixed also now, thanks

Comment: Is there a reason the error is handled outside the exception handler?

Comment: Yeah, because, the issue is not resource allocation/freeing, but a reply to the client, that an error has occurred and the "replying" code can't throw.

Comment: That doesn't seem like something you'd want to handle outside the exception handler, where it is executed regardless of whether an error has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule when it comes to `goto` (pretty much always): Assuming you don't KNOW of a specific reason to use `goto`, then don't. Basically, if you can't explain to someone else "I'm using `goto` here because ..." (and that "because ..." is a valid and good reason, not just "I'm a lazy programmer and can't be bothered to add another level if if/loop/etc" [that's my excuse every now and again!]).

<strike>`throw` will help with cleanup, which `goto` won't, so any local variables that need to be cleaned in the interveening scope will not be</strike>.

Using `throw` also allows you to have more than one level of function call to get out of, with one `throw` (in other words, you can be in a fairly deep call-stack, and get all the way out to a `catch` some levels further out).

It is also, as Wintermute points out, not valid C++ code, so it may not "work as expected" even if you have a very good reason to do this. You would then have to do a goto to just before the catch, and do a throw there to get into the catch block.

Comment: according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto goto will call dtors which means it cleans up

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment that using `goto` is very nearly never a good idea, but jumping out of a scope with `goto` does lead to the destruction of objects with automatic storage duration in that scope. This is defined in [stmt.jump] (6.6 (2)): "On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration that have been constructed in that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction."

Comment: "it may not work as expected" = it literally will never compile

Comment: `goto` won't "help with cleanup"? What? Where did you hear that? Please don't spread myths. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968/560648

Comment: Now fixed the "doesn't clean up" problem (left it in to not hide my ignorance)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Hehe :)