# How to restart a simple coin tossing game

Tags: python

I am using python 2.6.6

I am simply trying to restart the program based on user input from the very beginning.
thanks

```
import random
import time
print "You may press q to quit at any time"
print "You have an amount chances"
guess = 5
while True:
    chance = random.choice(['heads','tails'])
    person = raw_input(" heads or tails: ")
    print "*You have fliped the coin"
    time.sleep(1)
    if person == 'q':
         print " Nooo!"
    if person == 'q':
        break   
    if person == chance:
        print "correct"
    elif person != chance:
        print "Incorrect"
        guess -=1
    if guess == 0:
        a = raw_input(" Play again? ")
        if a == 'n':
            break
        if a == 'y':
            continue

#Figure out how to restart program
```

I am confused about the continue statement. 
Because if I use continue I never get the option of "play again" after the first time I enter 'y'.

Comment: Restart how? Restart the entire application or just ask the user to toss another coin?

Comment: Good point, should have asked.

Comment: Restart the entire application hence "from the very beginning"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [continue](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement at the point which you want the loop to be restarted. Like you are using `break` for breaking from the loop, the `continue` statement will restart the loop.

Not based on your question, but how to use `continue`:

```
while True: 
        choice = raw_input('What do you want? ')
        if choice == 'restart':
                continue
        else:
                break

print 'Break!'
```

Also:

```
choice = 'restart';

while choice == 'restart': 
        choice = raw_input('What do you want? ')

print 'Break!'
```

***Output***  :

```
What do you want? restart
What do you want? break
Break!
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420029/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop-from-inside-a-switch/1420100#1420100

Comment: @Dave: Interesting, I never looked at `while True` this way. But is it a bad practise in Python? I know the article mentions the fact being independent of languages, but just wondering...

Comment: @Dave: Somehow I still find `while True` better, but we will wait for others to give their opinions.

Comment: @sukhbir: I added a variation to your answer showing a way to eliminate `while True`. Less typing. Faster to read. Terminating condition cannot be overlooked. Eliminates the `continue` redundancy.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you indent the code properly, and then use `continue`. The loop will be called again.

Comment: @sukhbir: As a story, mine reads, "Initialize the user's choice. Loop while the user's choice is the word 'restart'. Ask the user to change the choice variable's value. The end." Yours reads, "Let's loop forever! Ask the user to change the choice variable's value. If they changed the value to 'restart' then we're going to continue looping (forever). Otherwise, we're not going to loop forever, so forget I said anything about looping forever. The end."

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

1. Factoring your code into functions; it makes it a lot more readable
2. Using helpful variable names
3. Not consuming your constants (after the first time through your code, how do you know how many guesses to start with?)

.

```
import random
import time

GUESSES = 5

def playGame():
    remaining = GUESSES
    correct = 0

    while remaining>0:
        hiddenValue = random.choice(('heads','tails'))
        person = raw_input('Heads or Tails?').lower()

        if person in ('q','quit','e','exit','bye'):
            print('Quitter!')
            break
        elif hiddenValue=='heads' and person in ('h','head','heads'):
            print('Correct!')
            correct += 1
        elif hiddenValue=='tails' and person in ('t','tail','tails'):
            print('Correct!')
            correct += 1
        else:
            print('Nope, sorry...')
            remaining -= 1

    print('You got {0} correct (out of {1})\n'.format(correct, correct+GUESSES-remaining))

def main():
    print("You may press q to quit at any time")
    print("You have {0} chances".format(GUESSES))

    while True:
        playGame()
        again = raw_input('Play again? (Y/n)').lower()
        if again in ('n','no','q','quit','e','exit','bye'):
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `random.seed` to initialize the random number generator. If you call it with the same value each time, the values from random.choice will repeat themselves.

Answer (score 0):

After you enter 'y', `guess == 0` will never be True.

Comment: Thanks...I just used the continue statement like suggested above and got that part of it working...however I will still consider all previous answers thanks.