# Breaking out of a while loop and switch in one go

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement, break

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420029/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop-from-inside-a-switch) concerning this problem in C++, but I'm using JavaScript here.
I'm basically in the same situation as the OP in the other post.

```
var input = prompt();
while(true) {
    switch(input) {
        case 'hi':
        break;
        case 'bye':
            //I want to break out of the switch and the loop here
        break;
    }
    /*Other code*/
}
```

Is there anyway to do that?

I also have multiple switches in the `/*Other code*/` section where the code should also break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in a function, then you can simply `return` to break out of both.

```
var input = prompt();
(function () {
    while(true) {
        switch(input) {
            case 'hi':
            break;
            case 'bye':
            return;
        }
        /*Other code*/
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use labels with the break statement in js

```
var input = prompt();

outside:
while(true) {
    switch(input) {
        case 'hi':
        break;
        case 'bye':
            //I want to break out of the switch and the loop here
        break outside;
    }
    /*Other code*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was one solution I approached but labels started to lose their readability when you have 10 switches :)

Comment: Are you sure you're writing a good code since you have 10 switches? ;)

Comment: Do you mean you have 10 different exit points/loops or 10 exit points in the switch statement that break the same loop. If the latter there is nothing stopping you breaking to the same label multiple times.

Comment: @Shomz It's a text-based game. I _might_ have over-exaggerated the number of switches I have :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same answer as in C++, or most other languages.  Basically, you just add a flag to tell your loop that it's done.

```
var input = prompt();
var keepGoing = true;
while(keepGoing) {
    switch(input) {
        case 'hi':
            break;
        case 'bye':
            //I want to break out of the switch and the loop here
            keepGoing = false;
            break;
    }
    // If you need to skip other code, then use this:
    if (!keepGoing)  break;
    /*Other code*/
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: I've tried this in my original code, but the `while` loop only checks the argument after everything inside of it has run, making it pretty much useless for stopping mid-execution.

Comment: That's why you have that extra check before the rest of your code after it.  See above.

Comment: Of course, the function option is pretty good too, and very JS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't  diminish readability in the name of "one less line of code". Make your intentions clear:

```
while (true) {
  var quit = false;

  switch(input) {
    case 'hi':
      break;

    case 'bye':
      quit = true;
      break;
  }

  if (quit)
    break;

  /*Other code*/
}
```

Comment: Same thing with Thought's solution: I have multiple switches so repeating the `if` statement to check for the value is impractical.