# Trigger Break Keyword Using Dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, switch-statement

I'm trying to make do with Python's lack of a switch statement and make code more efficient by using a dictionary, but I can't quite get what I'm looking for. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm working with

```
def zero():
    print("Yo")


def one():
    print("Hey")

options = {
    0: zero,
    1: one,
}
while True:
    response = int(input("Number: "))
    try:
        options.get(response)()
    except TypeError:
        print("Not a valid response")
```

and what I would like to see is some way to break the loop such as `2: break` that exits the loop. Currently I'm using sys.exit(0), but was wondering if it was possible to use the break keyword

Comment: Which language are you comparing to when you say "make do with Python's lack of a switch statement"? In a C/C++ switch statement, you'd have a similar problem: `break` would just exit the switch statement, and you'd need some other way to exit the loop (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420029/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop-from-inside-a-switch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a `LoopBreak` exception, raise that in a `two` function, and catch it in the loop to `break`:

```
class LoopBreak(Exception):
    pass    

def zero():
    print("Yo")

def one():
    print("Hey")

def two():
    raise LoopBreak

options = {
    0: zero,
    1: one,
    2: two
}

while True:
    response = int(input("Number: "))
    try:
        options.get(response)()
    except TypeError:
        print("Not a valid response")
    except LoopBreak:
        break
```

As a point of interest, this is similar to the pattern used natively by Python to stop generators; they raise a `StopIteration` exception when they run out of values to `yield`.

EDIT: As @mfripp correctly notes below, this will mask any `TypeError`s that are raised during execution of `zero` or `one`. I would change the main loop to this instead (so you don't have to rely on `TypeError`):

```
while True:
    response = int(input("Number: "))
    action = options.get(response)
    if action is None:
        print("Not a valid response")
        continue
    try:
        action()
    except LoopBreak:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this.

Here's a more robust version of @BingsF's clever answer (this one won't mask exceptions raised within the selected function):

```
class LoopBreak(Exception):
    pass    

def zero():
    print("Yo")

def one():
    print("Hey")

def two():
    raise LoopBreak

options = {
    0: zero,
    1: one,
    2: two
}

while True:
    try:
        response = int(input("Number: "))
        action = options[response]
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        print("Not a valid response")
        continue

    try:
        action()
    except LoopBreak:
        break
```

Or you could specify a special flag in your dictionary that will force a break:

```
def zero():
    print("Yo")

def one():
    print("Hey")

options = {
    0: zero,
    1: one,
    2: False
}

while True:
    try:
        response = int(input("Number: "))
        action = options[response]
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        print("Not a valid response")
        continue

    if action is False:
        break
    else:
        action()
```

Or use a special return value to force a break:

```
def zero():
    print("Yo")
    # returns None by default

def one():
    print("Hey")
    # returns None by default

def two():
    return False

options = {
    0: zero,
    1: one,
    2: two
}

while True:
    try:
        response = int(input("Number: "))
        action = options[response]
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        print("Not a valid response")
        continue

    if action() is False:
        break
```

The following code might be more "Pythonic". It could be infinitesimally slower than the approaches above, because it has to check all the `if` statements instead of looking up the function in a dictionary via a hash. But it may be easier to read and maintain.

```
while True:
    try:
        response = int(input("Number: "))
    except ValueError:
        response = -1    # error flag

    if response == 0:
        print("Yo")
    elif response == 1:
        print("Hey")
    elif response == 2:
        break
    else:
        print("Not a valid response")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
while True:
    response = int(input("Number: "))
    if response not in options:
        print("Not a valid response")
    else if response == 2:
        break
    else:
        options[response]()  # invoke the corresponding function
```

Incidentally, storing functions in a dictionary and having to invoke them like this  isn't exactly Pythonic. It's a lot nicer to simply explicitly enumerate the behaviour you need with successive `if`s.

Comment: Yes, that part works, but I'm looking for a way to exit the loop.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you think that I should just ditch the dictionary and stick with a bunch of if and elif statements?

Comment: @MANA624 I find in practice that if-else just makes reading code easier. Using a dictionary is usually best for _data_, and you can still use a dictionary for storing functions, but I've found in practice that explicit enumeration is actually a really nice thing in terms of code maintenance.

Comment: @MANA624 If you have a _lot_ of defined functions, using a dictionary is not a bad option. Whatever works best for your perceived use case (including readability and long-term maintenance) should be fine.