# Get the elements from an array -list under certain condition

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to print only the lines with the elements where the differences between columns(j) and columns (j+1) are equal to [0,1]). This means, in the given example I would keep only the first column (this dataset is just a little sample of a bigger one):

```
e= [([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 0]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [2, 0]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0])]


for i in range(0,12):
    for j in range(0,2):
        if ((np.array(e[i][j+1]) - np.array(e[i][j])) == [0,1]):
            print (e[i])
```

[image: pyt]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you subtract [0,2] (e[0][2] since e[0][3] doesn't exist) from? Do you want that to be printed? Also I think you made a tiny mistake in the way you created the numpy array

Comment: "I am trying to print only the lines with the elements where the differences between columns(j) and columns (j+1) are equal to [0,1])." So, of the results from the subtraction, *all* of the values need to match the reference value? And the error message suggests that you should either use `.any` or `.all` on the comparison result - I wonder which is appropriate, again, given that you want *all* of the values to match?

Answer (score 1):

You get a `ValueError` because the use of `==` here returns an array of `bool`s representing the equality of each element, not a `bool` itself. For example:

```
np.array([1, 2]) == [1, 2]
```

returns `np.array([True, True])`, *not* `True`. To get the result as a single boolean, use `all()`, which will return `True` if all elements in the `bool` array it is called on are `True`. The fixed `if` condition becomes:

```
((np.array(e[i][j+1]) - np.array(e[i][j])) == [0,1]).all()
```

With the fixed condition, the code ends up outputting:

```
([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2])
([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2])
([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3])
([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])
([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])
([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])
```

which seems right.

Answer (score 0):

So let me start with the issue.

When you compare a `numpy.array` with more than one element, you could get following result: `[True, False]`.

The `if`-statement does not know how to make sense of that and therefore you need to do exactly what the exception tells you to do, you need to add `.all()` at the end of the condition like this: `((np.array(e[i][j+1]) - np.array(e[i][j])) == [0,1]).all()`.

In the following i assume, based on your code, that you are looking for the rows that only contain columns with the difference `[0,1]` between them and not for the columns. (If i am mistaken, i am sorry. I just woke up.)

Let's move on.

Still there is one problem. With your solution you will get this result:

`([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2])`

`([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2])`

`([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3])`

`([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])`

`([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])`

`([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])`

But the result you want is this:

`([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2])`

Hence here is my solution based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859072/python-continuing-to-next-iteration-in-outer-loop).

```
import numpy as np

class ContinueEx(Exception):
    pass

continue_ex = ContinueEx()

_list = e= [([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 0]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 2]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 2], [2, 0]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]),
 ([0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0])]

for _inner_list in range(0,len(_list)):
    try:
        for _list_element in range(1, len(_list[_inner_list])):
            if not ((np.array(_list[_inner_list][_list_element]) - np.array(_list[_inner_list][_list_element-1])  == np.array([0,1]))).all():
                raise continue_ex
        print(_list[_inner_list])
    except ContinueEx:
        continue
```

I hope it was helpful.