# Why stack overflow occurs when merge sorting?

Tags: php, linked-list, stack-overflow, mergesort, doubly-linked-list

So having not waited for an answer in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432213/how-to-sort-spldoublylinkedlist), I decided to implement my data structure.
The problem I encountered: when sorting small lists, everything is fine, but when sorting a list with a size of 487 items, a stack overflow occurs in the `merge` method.

Here are the parts of the code responsible for sorting.
Any ideas?

```
private function mergeSort($node) {
        if ($node == null || $node->next == null) {
            return $node;
        }

        $second = $this->split($node);

        $node = $this->mergeSort($node);
        $second = $this->mergeSort($second);

        return $this->merge($node, $second);
    }

private function split(Word $word) {
        $fast = $word;
        $slow = $word;
        while ($fast->next !== null && $fast->next->next !== null) {
            $fast = $fast->next->next;
            $slow = $slow->next;
        }
        $temp = $slow->next;
        $slow->next = null;
        return $temp;
    }

private  function merge($first, $second) {
        if ($first === null) {
            return $second;
        }

        if ($second === null) {
            return $first;
        }

        if ($first->begin < $second->begin) {
            $first->next = $this->merge($first->next, $second);
            $first->next->prev = $first;
            $first->prev = null;
            return $first;
        } else {
            $second->next = $this->merge($first, $second->next);
            $second->next->prev = $second;
            $second->prev = null;
            return $second;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
//some code here 

$sortedLinedList = $linkedList->mergeSort($linkedList->head);
// stack overflow happens
```

**Update:**
I found out that the stack overflow does not always directly depend on the number of items in the list. Sometimes the stack can overflow with 350 elements, and sometimes with 487. Perhaps it depends on the data of the list itself. The only place where I use the node data directly is the comparison in the `merge` method. Maybe it happens because the variable "begin" contains the value of float type? I tried this:

```
round($first->begin, 2) < round($second->begin, 2)
```

but It didn't help me :(

Comment: `$node = $this->mergeSort($node);` calls the function recursively without change.

Comment: StackOverflow would occur to me too in that instance.

Comment: @B.Letz Hmm, but in this case, I am really not changing the node, I should change to one of the following nodes the `next` pointer to `null`. Isn't it?

Comment: If a function calls itself without changing any of the parameters, it will lead to an infinite loop of calling itself. Hence a Stack Overflow occurs

Comment: @B.Letz In fact, the parameters change because the node in the middle of the list changes its `next` pointer to `null`, thereby reducing the list by half. I mean the `split` function that I call before `$node = $this->mergeSort($node);`
And I also want to note that on small data sets of 200-300 elements everything works fine

Comment: A recursive merge is going to cause stack overflow for a large list. An iterative (looping) merge function should be used instead.

Comment: @rcgldr I found out the stack is overflowing with 487 items in the list. I think it's a really normal case when stack overflowing with 2^256 items in the list, but 487 items seem too little

Comment: I don't know php, so I wouldn't know about it's stack limitations. I would still recommend changing the merge function from recursive to iterative.

Comment: @rcgldr Most of the algorithms that I saw on Google, YouTube and SO are a recursive merge. My stack overflows with less than 500 items. Why in examples on phyton, c ++, java, the same code works fine, but in PHP
 it doesn’t work correctly? Maybe all the same error somewhere in my code?

Comment: Take a look at the merge function used in the 2 way bottom up merge sort, which is the second code example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844613/34845789#34845789) . The last example is a 4 way bottom up merge sort, not as common. Most libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort for a stable sort, such as a hybrid insertion / merge sort.