# Comparison sorting algorithms evaluating more than 2x elements at each step

Tags: sorting, computer-science, computer-science-theory

Comparison sorting algorithms normally evaluate 2x elements at each step (and do something different if the first element is smaller/bigger than or equal to the second element.)

**What are some examples of sorting algorithms, preferably stable ones, where more than 2x elements can be compared at each step?**

How would their performance be evaluated?

For sorting 2 elements at a time, a comparison sort cannot perform better than `O(n log n)` on average, what's the performance limit for sorting 3, 4, 5+ elements at a time?

Comment: Like if I had N horses and could race 4 of them at a time, what would be the most efficient way for me to race them to rank them fastest to slowest? *(yes, these are [spherical horses in a vacuum](https://boingboing.net/2010/10/30/a-science-joke-for-y.html) I'm talking about)*

Answer (score 0):

Any n-element at a time (for a specified fixed n) comparisons can be emulated by a series of some fixed number of 2-element at a time comparisons.  If you could do better than `O(n log n)` on n-at-a-time, it would automatically give you a better than `O(n log n)` algorithm for 2-at-a-time.

Comment: What’s the algorithm for subsequent comparisons? Let’s say I have 16 elements and can sort them 4 at a time. Once the first four, second four, …, last four are now in order, which 4 elements do I compare next? Tell me if I’m not making sense

Answer (score 0):

A k-way merge sort needs to determine which of k elements is the smallest. Using a standard 2x compare, it will take 3 compares to determine the smallest element. For a memory based sort, a 4-way merge sort will take the about the same number of operations as a 2-way merge sort, but gets a slight improvement in running time due to being more cache friendly. There is an example of a 4 way merge sort at the end of this answer:

[Optimized merge sort faster than quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844613/34845789#34845789)

On a system with 16 registers, 4-way is about as high as you can go. Plus trying to implement this without using a heap (which results in a slower algorithm) requires a large nested tree of if | else statements. It's already complex enough in the 4-way merge sort in that answer linked to above.

Comment: “It starts off doing 4 way merge, then when the end of a run is reached, it switches to 3 way merge, then 2 way merge” - I guess I’ve been looking to utilise close to same comparison capacity each time, but I’m open to the idea that won’t work

Comment: @Oleg - the merge operation requires all k runs be merged into a single run before moving on to the next set of k runs. Using multi-threading will help. With 4 threads, you split the array into 4 parts, then merge sort each of the 4 parts. Then 2 threads are used to merge the 4 parts into 2 parts, then a single thread to merge the 2 parts into a single part.

Answer (score 0):

The search for efficient ways to sort using as many simultaneous comparisons as possible is done with "sorting networks", Wikipedia has a nice article about it [Sorting Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).

> their sequence of comparisons is set in advance, regardless of the
> outcome of previous comparisons. In order to sort larger amounts of
> inputs, new sorting networks must be constructed. This independence of
> comparison sequences is useful for parallel execution

Here is the pseudocode for sorting networks for arrays from n=3 to n=7.

```
Compare(v, i, j) {
 if (v[j] < v[i]) Swap(v, i, j);
}

SortingNetwork3(v) {
    Compare(v, 0, 2);
    Compare(v, 0, 1);
    Compare(v, 1, 2);
}

SortingNetwork4(v) {
    Compare(v, 0, 2); Compare(v, 1, 3);
    Compare(v, 0, 1); Compare(v, 2, 3);
    Compare(v, 1, 2);
}

SortingNetwork5(v) {
    Compare(v, 0, 3); Compare(v, 1, 4);
    Compare(v, 0, 2); Compare(v, 1, 3);
    Compare(v, 0, 1); Compare(v, 2, 4);
    Compare(v, 1, 2); Compare(v, 3, 4);
    Compare(v, 2, 3);
}

SortingNetwork6(v) {
    Compare(v, 0, 5); Compare(v, 1, 3); Compare(v, 2, 4);
    Compare(v, 1, 2); Compare(v, 3, 4);
    Compare(v, 0, 3); Compare(v, 2, 5);
    Compare(v, 0, 1); Compare(v, 2, 3); Compare(v, 4, 5);
    Compare(v, 1, 2); Compare(v, 3, 4);
}

SortingNetwork7(v) {
    Compare(v, 0, 6); Compare(v, 2, 3); Compare(v, 4, 5);
    Compare(v, 0, 2); Compare(v, 1, 4); Compare(v, 3, 6);
    Compare(v, 0, 1); Compare(v, 2, 5); Compare(v, 3, 4);
    Compare(v, 1, 2); Compare(v, 4, 6);
    Compare(v, 2, 3); Compare(v, 4, 5);
    Compare(v, 1, 2); Compare(v, 3, 4); Compare(v, 5, 6);
}
```

Comparisons on the same row (step) can be done simultaneously, using multithreading, vectorization or specialized hardware.

The theoretical limit for sorting n elements is O(log(n)) number of steps, with n sufficient big, but to construct an optimal sorting network is a NP problem, there are algoritms to create sorting networks with O(log^2(n)) steps. Currently there are known optimal sorting networks for n up to 17. Note that the number of comparisons is still O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

For sorting four byte-elements at once, you can use lookup tables.

```
var = 4 bytes joined into 32bit
sorted = lut[var]; // buy RAM
extract bytes from sorted
O(1)
```

But RAM latency will make it slow unless byte values tend to hit L1 cache.

If element values are very limited like integers 0,1,2,3 then it needs only 2 bits per value. Then you can do sorting at 4 per operation using only 256 sized lookup table which fits L1.

If values are just 0 and 1, then you dont even need lookup table. Just count the 1s in the variable, there are cpu instructions to do it in O(1).

```
// 32 bits at once
count=popcnt(var)
sorted=(0xFFFFFFFF<<(32-count))
O(1) and fast
```

---

Cpu pipelines instructions so as long as you compare(&swap) independent elements, you get parallelism depending on depth of pipeline.

Cpu has simd units so that you can compare 2,4,8,16 32bit elements at once and selectively choose greater/lesser in each one. Possibly these are also pipelined so you get way higher parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same. While you are talking about comparative sorting it is actually a decision tree. Therefore it doesn't really matter how many elements you are sorting the limit comes from the requirement of comparing 2 elements.

[image]