# I made this program to learn goto use. but did some mistakes somewhere

Tags: c, goto

here I used "goto" and when I call one goto like name1 with if else it all the values of gotos. like all the name1 name2 name3 name4. Help!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Name number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    if(num==1)
    goto name1;
    else
    goto name2;
    name1:
      printf("M");
    name2:
      printf("A");
    name3:
      printf("I");
    name4:
      printf("Y");

    return 0;
}
```

if I give the value 1 or 2 it shows MAIY

Comment: Can't reproduce! When I enter 2 I see (as expected) "AIY".

Comment: Cannot reproduce. When I enter `2` it outputs `AIY`. You might like to read [Is it ever advantageous to use 'goto' in a language that supports loops and functions? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/is-it-ever-advantageous-to-use-goto-in-a-language-that-supports-loops-and-func)

Comment: Here´s another "Can´t reproduce"-r. If I input `2` I do also get `AIY` instead of `MAIY`. How do you compile?

Comment: I think you learned the lesson: avoid gotos. It is an antipattern and makes your code brittle.

Comment: Yeah - it's a waste of effort to learn about goto and then unlearn it after.  Best to skip both steps:)

Answer (score 2):

> "*when I call one goto like name1 with if else it all the values of gotos. like all the name1 name2 name3 name4. Help!!!*"

It seems that you misunderstanding the use of `goto`. A `goto` label doesn´t specify a certain group of statements (compound statement/block) or just a single statement to it like it is f.e. to a particular condition match to a `if`/`elseif` chain or a `switch`/`case` statement.

The `goto name1` statement just let you **jump** to the position of the label `name1`. Nothing more, nothing less.

If you want to achieve what you described, use a `switch` like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num;
    printf("Name number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    switch(num) {

    case 1:
      printf("M");
      break;

    case 2:
      printf("A");
      break;

    case 3:
      printf("I");
      break;

    case 4:
      printf("Y");
      break;

    default:
      break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that the use of `goto` as you did is commonly deprecated.

You should take a look at these posts:

[Is it ever advantageous to use 'goto' in a language that supports loops and functions? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/is-it-ever-advantageous-to-use-goto-in-a-language-that-supports-loops-and-func)

[GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `switch` you can do as the answer of @Roberts. But if you still want to use `goto` for this case, you can add new label after each `printf` function to break out some statement you do not want to execute. For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Name number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    if(num==1)
       goto name1;
    else
       goto name2;
    name1:
      printf("M");
      goto end_name;
    name2:
      printf("A");
      goto end_name;
    name3:
      printf("I");
      goto end_name;
    name4:
      printf("Y");
    end_name:
       printf("\nHello World ===> Do something else from here\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output like:

```
Name number                                                                                                             
1                                                                                                                       
M                                                                                                                       
Hello World ===> Do something else from here
```

Comment: Clever! :-) Although this kind of use of `goto` is still deprecated. You probably should mention it.

Comment: Yes, just think about the mimic of `break` in `switch`