# Is there a function in C++ similar to ":menu" in Batch?

Tags: c++, batch-file

I'm a teenager trying to learn C++. I used to use Batch because all I wanted to program at that time was simple CYOA games. In batch, there's a system that divides codes like so:

```
@echo off
[Pretend there's some elaborate code here]
...
:menu
echo Would you like to go again?
echo 1. Yes
echo 2. No
set /P choice1="Choice: "
set choice=
if '%choice%'=='1' goto :menu
if '%choice%'=='2' exit
```

and then 'goto :menu' would take you back to the start of that section and redo the code again. I'm aware of loops, but is there a function that works just like this? If it helps, here's my (very simple) code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int product;
    int sum;
    string response;
    cout << "Enter two numbers separated by commas.\n";
    cin >> num1, num2;
    product = num1 * num2;
    sum = num1 + num2;
    
    if (product>sum){
        cout << "The product is larger than the sum.";
    }
    else{
    cout << "The sum is larger than the product.";
    }
    cout << "Would you like to do this again? Y/N\n";
    cin >> response
    if (response==Y)
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `:menu` isn't really a function in `.BAT` files, is it? Isn't it a label? Anyway, you can do the same in C++ - but you should very rarely do that since there are better (more easy to follow) ways to control the program flow.

Comment: It is a label, my bad. I forgot the name :/

Comment: 1. Your way of asking for choice is "wrong". Use [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead. 2. Don't learn batch, learn powershell instead which is cleaner and has no legacy issues

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Hint:  `std::toupper` and `std::transform(response.begin(), response.end(), response.begin(), toupper)`  These are methods to convert the response to upper case so you only need to make one comparison.  BTW, you need to compare to string literals, e.g. `response == "Y"`

Comment: For menu selection and processing, the are a plethora of methods.  Search the internet for "c++ menu selection".  Some use `switch` statements, others use table driven with function pointers.

Comment: C++ has `goto`, too, but using it is frowned upon. The idiomatic way to repeat until getting a "n" response is by enclosing everything in a `while (true)` loop and using `break` (or `return`) to leave the loop when the user says to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C++ has `goto`. What you are doing in the batch file is essentially a loop and  you should use a `while` loop in the equivalent C++.

`goto` programming easily leads to code that is difficult to understand or to modify. Instead, you should use structured programming with `if` statements, `for` and `while` loops, and functions. They are the bread and butter of C++ and many other programming languages.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: sometimes `goto` will make a cleaner code, but most of the time it'll make the code less readable. [Is it ever advantageous to use 'goto' in a language that supports loops and functions? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24451/995714), [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517726/995714), [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/995714)

Comment: `goto` is that screwdriver in your toolbox with the really weirdly-shaped head. It should only come out of the box when you have the really weirdly-shaped screw. And even the it may be easier to find a way to use a regular screw. In the real world of programming, it's often harder to get a `goto` through a code review, even when it's used perfectly and you can prove it, than it is to deal with the clunkier alternative. For one thing, someone will try to replace the `goto` and totally <expletive deleted> things up sooner or later.