# can someone tell me why this code skips to the next input

Tags: c

I am trying to read students data (name, department, roll, sgpa, cgpa), I used `fgets` function to read name and department, but it skips to the department and can't read name.
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char department[50];
    int roll;
    float sgpa[12];
    float cgpa;
} Student;

void add(FILE *fp);
void modify(FILE *fp);
void display(FILE *fp);
FILE * del(FILE * fp);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int option;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("db.txt", "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("db.txt", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Can't open the database");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\t1. Add Student");
    printf("\n\t2. Modify Student");
    printf("\n\t3. Show All Student");
    printf("\n\t4. Remove Student");
    printf("\n\tEnter Your Option :--> ");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            add(fp);
            break;
        case 2:
            // modify(fp);
            break;
        case 3:
            // display(fp);
            break;
        case 4:
            // fp = del(fp);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unkonw option\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(FILE *fp) {
    Student std;
    int i;
    float cgpa;
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    printf("\n\tEnter Full Name of Student: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(std.name,100,stdin);
    std.name[strlen(std.name)-1]='\0';
    printf("\n\tEnter Depertment Name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(std.department,50,stdin);
    std.department[strlen(std.department)-1]='\0';
    printf("\n\tEnter Roll number: ");
    scanf("%d",&std.roll);
    printf("\n\tEnter SGPA for 12 semesters\n");
    for(i=0,cgpa=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&std.sgpa[i]);
        cgpa+=std.sgpa[i];
    }
    cgpa/=12.0;
    std.cgpa=cgpa;
    fwrite(&std,sizeof(std),1,fp);
}
```

Comment: `strlen` only works with strings and not with char arrays. The difference between a string and a char array is, that a string must have a `'\0'`, a char array needn't to have one. _"The C library function size_t strlen(const char *str) computes the length of the string str up to, but not including the terminating null character."_ So when you use `strlen` on a not `'\0'` terminated char array, you might get a buffer overflow.

Comment: Yes. Your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) could tell you, if you compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. But before, **read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)**

Answer (score -1):

[Is there a way of limiting scanf in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065931/is-there-a-way-of-limiting-scanf-in-c/65066189#65066189)

I did this, if you're having that many problems with string input giving an eye on my other answer might help you

Here's a more specific answer to your problem on message you place what you wanna print before the input and StringInput you place the array you're using to hold the message
I hope this works since you also use a array for it

also i see this:

```
fp = fopen("db.txt", "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("db.txt", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Can't open the database");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

which may not be what you want because if it fails because of a sudden glitch by using wb+ you will overwrite it

“r+” – Searches file. Opens the file for both reading and writing. If opened successfully, fopen() loads it into memory and sets up a pointer which points to the first character in it. Returns NULL, if unable to open the file.

“w+” – Searches file. If the file exists, its contents are overwritten. If the file doesn’t exist, a new file is created. Returns NULL, if unable to open the file.

FUNCAUX_MAX_STRING is a macro and you define it like so:

```
#define FUNCAUX_MAX_STRING 100
```

This makes it so that the number or elements is 100 and you can easily change every number thats using the macro by simply changing the value once

```
void readString(char message[FUNCAUX_MAX_STRING], char StringInput[FUNCAUX_MAX_STRING], int maxChars)
{
    int sizeString;

    do          // Repete leitura caso sejam obtidas strings vazias
    {
        printf("%s", message);
        fgets(StringInput, maxChars, stdin);

        sizeString = strlen(StringInput);

        if (sizeString == 1)
        {
             printf("Nao foram introduzidos caracteres!!! . apenas carregou no ENTER \n\n");  
        }

    }
    while (sizeString == 1);

    if(StringInput[sizeString-1] != '\n') 
    {
        cleanBufferStdin(); 
    }
    else
    {
        StringInput[sizeString-1] = '\0';   
    }

}
void cleanBufferStdin(void)
{
    char chr;
    do
    {
        chr = getchar();
    }
    while (chr != '\n' && chr != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Answers should answer. The answer to the question should be contained in the posted answer, not presented merely as a link to somewhere else. And, if a question is a duplicate that can be fully answered with just a link to somewhere else, it should be closed as a duplicate rather than answered.

Comment: @EricPostpischil its not a complete duplicate but just using a slightly modified code would answer i think

Comment: @EricPostpischil what about now can you remove the downvote? or should i remove the link all together?