# Switch with goto statement in function keeps running ad infinitum?

Tags: c

This is the relevant code, I'm trying to write a function to pick type of account and when I run this, it keeps running in a weird loop. Any solutions?

```
  void AccType(){
wrongInput:;
        int typCho;
        printf("What type of account do you want to open?\nPress 1 for Current\n2 for savings\n3 for retirement:\n");
        scanf("%d",typCho);
        switch (typCho) {
        case 1:
                strcpy(PracRec.AccTyp,"Current");
                break;
        case 2:
                strcpy(PracRec.AccTyp,"Savings");
                break;
        case 3:
                strcpy(PracRec.AccTyp,"Retirement");
                break;
        default:
                printf("Please enter a valid choice!!\n");
                goto wrongInput;
        }
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* here `scanf("%d",typCho);` by passing `int` where `int*` required and using an (indeterminate) value of uninitialied non-static local variable. Usually it will lead to Segmentation Fault. You are (un)lucky!

Comment: ah thanks I'm still new to this whole programming stuff so I keep making these newbie mistakes

Comment: You shouldn't try to create loops with `goto` – instead use real loop semantics (`for`, `while`, `do - while`). As you'd have a nested loop and switch, you might use `goto` to exit the loop, though. The difference? Well, an explicit loop shows immediately what's going on, leaving nested loops with `goto` is commen/accepted practice. A loop instantiated with `goto` is much less clearly visible.

Comment: Regarding when to use `goto`: 1. [Is it ever advantageous to use 'goto' in a language that supports loops and functions? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24451/12149471) 2. [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/12149471)

Comment: @Bas_Anar: Compiler warnings can help avoid these "newbie mistakes".  For instance `gcc -Wall` gives you a warning about your `scanf` bug: https://godbolt.org/z/MEc8effz7.  Figure out how to turn on warnings, always always use them, and never never ignore them!  If you can't figure out what a warning means, ask, but don't even try to run your code until you've got it resolved.

Comment: Thank you everyone, this is some great advice! I'll be sure to avoid using goto statements from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `scanf` needs to be a pointer (memory adress) to an integer...

So, replace the line:

```
scanf("%d",typCho);
```

with:

```
scanf("%d", &typCho);
```

`&` is an operator that returns the memory address of the operand at right.

This is needed because `scanf` is going to change the value inside the memory address which relates to the variable.

When you put only `typCho` as the argument, it probably made the program to write the input at a random memory location, as the variable was also uninitialized.

Also, consider avoiding the use of `goto`, as pointed in the previous comments.

You could easily do the same thing with a construct like:

```
do { ...code... } while (condition);
```