# goto statement in language standard

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, goto

Most people nowadays don't use `goto` statement in their code. Good. In SO there are many threads on `goto` usage, all of them "allowing" it for exiting deep loops.

To show a few:

[GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

[What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)

[Are there any legitimate use-cases for "goto" in a language that supports loops and functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/are-there-any-legitimate-use-cases-for-goto-in-a-language-that-supports-loops/2809622#2809622)

[Examples of good gotos in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c)

I looked at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto), which tells:

> Used when it is otherwise impossible to transfer control to the
> desired location using other statements.

What rings my bells is "*otherwise impossible*"

Can any body show examples where `goto` can't be avoided?

Note: I've tagged this question as "C++", just because I'm more interested in C++ samples. Any other language is good for me.

Comment: I've never run into a case in C or C++ where `goto` could not be avoided.  I've run into cases (with state machines in C and C++, and with error handling in C) where `goto` made the code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that it can always be avoided, but what I can't guarantee is that the `goto`-free version will be less convoluted than the `goto` version. The thing is, whenever you use `goto`, no matter how better suited `goto` may be for the code's readability,  you'll spend the rest of your life explaining and justifying why you used `goto`, and this eats up much more time than writing your way around nearly all uses of `goto`. And most uses of `goto` are just a bad idea, anyway.

Comment: @Eljay Yeah, "succinct and readable" are reasons, but I'm asking for "otherwise impossible"

Comment: I have been working in projects where `goto` were *mandatory* according to company coding policies. It was required because the single-return requirements in the policies.

Comment: I'd say it's an unfortunate choice of words in cppreference. You can always rewrite code in such a way that `goto` is avoided. What I think was implied by person writing that sentence is that you don't want to refactor everything, but you still want to transfer the control somewhere that you can't normally.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Perhaps the standard accepts "company coding policies" as a synonimum for "otherwise impossible"

Comment: Please note that cppreference, while a very good reference, is not the same as the C++ standard. I doubt the actual standard have a sentence like that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Seems you're right. Searching for "stmt.goto" gives a couple of entries [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.goto) and [this](https://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDD38/ISOCPP/stmt.goto.html). None says "impossible". I'll accept your comment as a valid answer.

Comment: I think goto is still in C++ becuase of legacy reasons (backward compatibility with old style "C" code). But in over 30 years of C++ I never ever needed it, and I can't think of a legitimate use case.

Comment: If you have nested loops and want to `break`/`continue` on one of the outer loops, the least contorted way may be a `goto`. Java has labeled continue/break for this, C++ does not.

Comment: I've used `goto` once or twice to break out of deeply nested loops where a "win" condition was found and continuing the loops made no sense. Sure, I could have set a variable that was tested on each iteration to bail out or something else (even something much nastier like `setjmp`/`longjmp`), but `goto` seemed the cleanest approach. It's certainly not the first tool you should reach for in the toolbox, but once in a while it *is* the best tool and when it is; use it.

Comment: To break a deep inner loop wrap the context in an IIILE; and break it with a `return`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude single-return policy is normally used in resource intensive C programming, to simplify the cleanup logic. That's not a good option for C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, it's been proven (like a mathematical proof) that anything you can do with goto's, you can also do without them. But in some cases, you end up with duplicated code, or more complex control structures.

But the sentence in question only talks about transferring control to a place that you couldn't with other control structures. The primary example of this would be transferring control into the body of a loop. For example, consider the fairly common requirement to print out some numbers (or strings, etc.) separated by commas, so we have commas *between* the items, but not before the first or after the last. One way to do this is something like this:

```cpp
goto start;
while (i < n) {
    print(',');
start:
    print(input[i++]);
}
```

The only way to transfer control directly into the middle of the loop body like this is a `goto`. The sole alternative is to simply not transfer control into the middle of the loop body at all. And you can certainly do that:

```cpp
bool first = true;
while (i < n) {
    if (!first) {
        print(',');
    }
    first = false;
    print(input[i++]);
}
```

Of course there are other possibilities as well. But for the specific requirement of transferring control into the middle of the loop body, `goto` is the only thing that works.

Comment: While I was thinking of "unavoidable use of goto" this answer explains very well the wording of cppreference, "...impossible to transfer control to the desired location"

Comment: Knuth called it a _loop and a half:_ `for(;;) { print(input[i]); if (++i == n) break; print(','); }` It handles most cases where you "must" jump into the middle of a loop. Rather than use a `goto`, you just move the loop termination test into the middle of the loop. As a bonus, it reads a lot better than the out-of-order examples given above.

Comment: @tbxfreeware: It's not really changing much--a `break` is just as much a `goto` as a `goto` is.

Comment: Right! Under the hood, so is `for(;;)`. Perhaps my brain has been poisoned, because it has not written `goto` in a program for more years than I can remember, but I still find the version with the test in the middle of the loop to be easier to read, and to be the more "natural" statement of the algorithm. It rubs me wrong when the statement that prints the comma appears _before_ the statement that prints the first value.

Comment: @tbxfreeware: I don't even mean that far under the hood though. Even (for example) in the C standard, `break`, `goto`, `continue` and `return` are all considered "Jump Statements".

Comment: @tbxfreeware You could do that, but the goto version is substantially cleaner.